# Can I declare variables inside an Objective-C switch statement?

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I think I'm going blind, because I can't figure out where the syntax error is in this code:

```
if( cell == nil ) {
    titledCell = [ [ [ TitledCell alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ] autorelease
    ];

    switch( cellNumber ) {
        case 1:
            NSString *viewDataKey = @"Name";
etc...
```

When I try to compile it, I'm getting an *Error: syntax error before '*' token* on the last line.

Sorry for such a basic question, but what am I missing?

Comment: What kind of variable is cellNumber? The switch statement is from C, so using Objective-C types can trip it up.

Comment: C only supports integral-like objects for `switch/case`, and I'd expect a different error message if that were the problem here.

Comment: Does Objective-C follow C99 (and C++) and allow you to declare variables anywhere, or can you only do so at the start of a block?  If you are constrained to declare them at the start of a block, then you could fix your syntax error by putting a '`{`' after the '`:`' of '`case 1:`' and a matching '`}`' before the end of the case.

Comment: I don't know if Objective-C is forked off of C89 or if it borrows C99/C++ constructs too.  Either way, jumping *over* declarations is really scary...

Comment: You can set C89 or C99 (or GNU99) as a build property in Xcode; Objective-C lays on top of your choice of C standards.

Comment: I believe C99 is the default (declaring an incrementor inside a for loop works: for (int i =0;...), and I believe that's C99).

Comment: Related, valuable question and answer, focusing in C only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I don't have a suitable Objective-C compiler on hand, but as long as the C constructs are identical:

`switch { … }` gives you **one** block-level scope, not one for each `case`.  Declaring a variable anywhere other than the beginning of the scope is illegal, and inside a `switch` is *especially* dangerous because its initialization may be jumped over.

Do either of the following resolve the issue?

```
NSString *viewDataKey;
switch (cellNumber) {
    case 1:
        viewDataKey = @"Name";
    …
}

switch (cellNumber) {
    case 1: {
        NSString *viewDataKey = @"Name";
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: wrt/ `Declaring a variable anywhere other than the beginning of the scope is illegal`.  This is not true in C99.  C99 both allows for this and defines the semantics of what happens when "control jumps past a declaration" and the value of that declaration in such cases.

Comment: I forgot to indicate which option solved the problem, oops. I used the top one to solve the problem - I don't think I tested the second suggestion, which is too bad, because you guys look like you were having a great discussion!

Answer (score 20):

You can't declare a variable at the beginning of a case statement. Make a test case that just consists of that and you'll get the same error.

It doesn't have to do with variables being declared in the middle of a block — even adopting a standard that allows that won't make GCC accept a declaration at the beginning of a case statement. It appears that GCC views the case label as part of the line and thus won't allow a declaration there.

A simple workaround is just to put a semicolon at the beginning of the case so the declaration is not at the start.

Comment: False.  `switch (0) { int i; }` compiles perfectly fine even back in C89.

Comment: Not false. I just ran your example from Aragorn's post through GCC and got the same error.

Comment: I'm claiming that "can't declare a variable in a case statement" is false.  Try giving GCC the tiny example in my previous comment.

Comment: There is no case statement in your comment, so it's irrelevant to the content of my post. Also, I have clarified my answer slightly.

Comment: Oh, I see, you were talking about the `case` label specifically and not the `switch`.  Confusing to talk about the "beginning" of it -- `case` is just a *label*, and as such can only label statements.  That is a valid point.

Comment: Semicolon at the beginning of the case statement doesn't solve the problem, which is that a jump across the initialization of a variable is happening.  Every good compiler will warn about this.  The correct fix is to enclose the case statement in brackets, giving the variable a well-defined scope.

Comment: @Dan: GCC does not warn about this. I tested it.

Comment: The poster of this answer is correct.  The root of the problem lies in the C99 BNF grammar, which (loosely) defines a labeled statement as: `...: statement`.  In short, there is no way to get from `statement` to `declaration`.  A `compound-statement` (ie, `{ ... }`) (loosely) defines the `...` part as `zero or more block-items`, with block-item (loosely) defined as a `statement or declaration`.  Also, the comment by @Dan Olson is both wrong and does not apply to C99, which very clearly defines the semantics of inter-mixed declarations and statements wrt/ initialization (C99 6.8.6.1, etc).

Answer (score 4):

In C you only can declare variables at the begining of a block before any non-declare statements.

```
{
   /* you can declare variables here */

   /* block statements */

   /* You can't declare variables here */
}
```

In C++ you can declare variables any where you need them.

Comment: `switch (1) { case 0: int i = 1; break; default: /* wtf is i? */; }` Even if you can declare variables everywhere, inside a `switch` is *dangerous*.

Comment: with visual studio 2008 compiling a c file. is -> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

=)

Comment: Skipping over initializers in C++ is even more dangerous than in C, and MSVC is more of a C++ compiler than a C compiler.  I'm not surprised that it doesn't like this junk.

Comment: In C mode (/TC) it gives the error and in C++ mode (/TP) it compile without error. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable within a switch statement but you will have to create it within a block so that the scope of that variable is defined.

Example:

```
switch(number){

    case 1:
        {
            // Create object here
            // object is defined only for the scope of this block
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            // etc.
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
```

Comment: This is a new answer to a very old question with an accepted answer.  What does your answer provide that the others do not?

Comment: This was meant to be an alternative to the 1st switch statement presented in the accepted answer. At the time of posting I had not noticed the bracket inline with the case statement in the 2nd switch statement provided.

Answer (score 1):

Might it not be valid to declare a variable within a switch block?

Comment: As I remarked on Chuck's answer: `switch (0) { int i; }` is valid C89, and Objective-C is a true superset of C (unlike C++), so everything legal in C (modulo stolen identifiers) is legal in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the warning:

1.Insert one `;` in the first line of your case block

2.Put codes inside braces