# Compile Error with: switch, "expected expression before"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, xcode3.2

Cut to the chase I have recreated my problem as it is fairly self explanatory.

**this complies without error:**

```
switch (n) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"");
        NSString *aStr;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

**this compiles with error** and it's only missing the NSLog():

```
switch (n) {
    case 1:
        NSString *aStr;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

it throws an error at compile "*Expected expression before 'NSString'*"

Am I missing something here?

Comment: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180550/weird-switch-error-in-obj-c/1181106#1181106>

Comment: I remember a switch/case statement with a similar error, it used to disappear when I add a comment somewhere within the case block.. Magic

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In normal C you'd have to enclose this in brackets in both cases.  I suspect this may fix your problem:

```
case 1:
{
    NSLog(@"");
    NSString *aStr;
    break;
}
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement) for more info.

Another way to get around this problem is to put a statement between the case label and the first declaration as you've done in your working example above.  See the comments and Quinn Taylor's answer for more info.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't try the bracket approach.

Comment: Yes this fixes the problem. I was just running with xcode's code fill which doesn't use them. Thanks.

Comment: I've come across this problem before, I solved it using { } myself, good to see it was the correct solution. +1 for you Dan.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use brackets. Putting an empty statement (`;`) after the `case` label works, too. The reason for the error and the reason why both solutions work is that a label, including a `case` label, can only precede a statement. Declarations aren't statements in C (C99 §6.7, §6.8, §6.8.2) and Objective-C, so you can't put a label immediately before a declaration. Thus the solutions: Either put a statement (such as `;` or `NSLog(@"");`) between the label and declaration, or wrap the declaration inside a compound statement (the brackets) following the label.

Answer (score 26):

You can't declare a variable as the *first* statement in a `case` without brackets, and in many other contexts in C-based languages. See [Declaring variables inside a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/) for details.

Answer (score 4):

```
case 0: {
    Loading my nib file;
    break; 
}
case 1: {
    Loading another nib file;
    break; 
}
Note that if you don't have an assignment (x = y) right after the case it won't be a problem. For example:
```