# Call of UIViewController inside Switch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsdictionary

Hi I have here a code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and my problem is i cannot use `switch` case by calling a `UIViewController`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

TaskList *account = nil;
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    account = [_forCheckerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    account = [_forApprovalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    account = [_forVerificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

NSDictionary *funcColors = (NSDictionary*)[dict objectForKey:@"funcTags"];
int tag = [[funcColors objectForKey:[account funcCd]] intValue];
FundTransferOwnViewController *sc = [[FundTransferOwnViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
switch (tag) {
    case 10: //aca
        AutoCreditViewController *sc = [[AutoCreditViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}}
```

On case 10, i am calling `AutoCreditViewController`, it always prompts with a red exclamation point saying "**Expected Expression**".

Comment: can you past screen shot here

Comment: im not still able to post an image here in stack overflow. :(

Comment: Try placing the code inside case 10 within {...}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile Error with: switch, "expected expression before"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036819/compile-error-with-switch-expected-expression-before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the switch case within ***braces { }*** like

```
switch (tag) 
{
   case 10: 
   {
      AutoCreditViewController *sc = [[AutoCreditViewController alloc]init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
      break;
    }
   default:
      break;
 }
```

Comment: what is the reason for this why curly braces in objective c.

Comment: @AniketKote Check this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 0):

When initialising a new object within a switch you need to add curly braces {.
So your switch should look like this:

```
switch (tag) {
    case 10:
        {
            AutoCreditViewController *sc = [[AutoCreditViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your both "sc" Objects are same name but diff Class , keep both different then see what will happn.