# Attribution in first line on switch statement make a error in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

Why the code doesn't work unless I remove the comment?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num = 5;
    switch(num){
        case 5:
            //printf("");
            int another = 1;
            printf("%d", num+another);
            break;
    }
}
```

gcc returns an error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:7:13: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: Thanks @Donal , you explained to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is outlined here: [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

As a workaround, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num = 5;
    switch(num){
        case 5:;
            //printf("");
            int another = 1;
            printf("%d", num+another);
            break;
    }
}
```

include a semicolon after the case as a workaround.Fool the compiler into thinking a statement follows and not a declaration. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180550/weird-switch-error-in-obj-c/1181106#1181106%3E)