# error with switch case and exptected expression

Tags: objective-c

Sorry to ask this (I rarely use switch statements) but I am getting an error with this but it seems valid to me (but obviously isn't):

```
  NSInteger section=indexPath.section;

  switch(section){
    case 0:
      Item *mi = self.miArray[indexPath.row]; // <- expected expression
      ...
      return cell;
      break;
    case 1:
      Item *mi = self.miArray[indexPath.row];
      break;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird Switch error in Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180550/weird-switch-error-in-obj-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put the case in braces (`case 0: { Item *mi ... }`) or add a ; after the case statement (`case 0:;`).

Either of that should help but I actually forgot why this is necessary.

Found an explanation here: [Weird Switch error in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180550/weird-switch-error-in-obj-c/1181106#1181106%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Declaration is not allowed within switch.
Declare Item before entering to switch and do the initialization within the switch.