# switch/case problem

Tags: iphone

If i try to create variable in case statement it gives me build erroe
Can anyone clue me in why this syntax gets me a build error ("expected expression before 'NSMutableArray'").

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring variables inside a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding brackets {} in your case statement to be able to declare variables, like this:

```
switch (my_switch_statement)
{
     case my_switch_case: 
     {
         NSMutableArray *my_switch_array;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit. Adding curly braces fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you try do something like:

```
switch (...){
  case someCase:
        NSMutableArray *array = ...
        break;
...
}
```

c (and so objective-c) does not allow to declare variables inside switch-case statement. If you want to do that you must limit the variable scope by putting your code inside {} block:

```
switch (...){
  case someCase:{
        NSMutableArray *array = ...
  }
        break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally you will want to declare the variable outside of the scope of the switch, just like any conditional block of code.

```
NSString * valueString;

int i = 1;

switch(i){

    case 0:

         valueString = @"case 0";

    break;

    case 1:

         valueString = @"case 1";

    break;

    default:

         valueString = @"not case 1 or 0";

    break;

}

//valueString=>@"case 1"
```