# Strange Switch Parse error

Tags: objective-c

```
switch (indexPath.section) {  
  case 0: //products used  
    NSString * chemical = [selectedChemicals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = chemical;  
    break;  
  case 1: //areas sprayed  
    return [selectedAreas count];  
    break;  
  case 2://target pests  
    return [selectedPests count];  
    break;  
  case 3://notes  
    return 1;  
    break;  
}
```

gives me:          "/Users/grady/programming/ObjectivelyBetter/bioguard/Classes/JobWizardViewController.m:147: error: 'chemical' undeclared (first use in this function)"

putting a blank semi-colon at the beginning of the case fixes it.

```
switch (indexPath.section) {  
  case 0: //products used  
    ;  
    NSString * chemical = [selectedChemicals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = chemical;  
    break;  
  case 1: //areas sprayed  
    return [selectedAreas count];  
    break;  
  case 2://target pests  
    return [selectedPests count];  
    break;  
  case 3://notes  
    return 1;  
    break;  
}
```

Comment: You don't need to manually put all the `&nbsp;` to format your code; just select it and click the button that looks like "{ }".

Comment: thank you, it was highly annoying.

Comment: please post in your code again and click the "{}" button. that will also result in color highlighted code.

Comment: Someone else has already done that, just waiting for edit approval.

Comment: Just a suggestion, not a solution to your question. You don't need the break statements after the return.

Comment: And it's a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare variables within a `case` statement, it's a good practice (and required to avoid these kinds of errors) to enclose the statements inside curly braces, e.g.

```
case 0:
    {
        int i = 0;
        ....
        break;
    }
```

Not sure why a semicolon along would have "solved" the issue. That's kind of odd... the curly braces are what you need.

In your particular case you could also just eliminate the local variable declaration and set the cell textLabel like so:

```
  cell.textLabel.text = [selectedChemicals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: you're right, as for the weirdness... I think I have it figured out sort of, it has to do with switch expansion.

the semicolon is the whole expression for the first case, then it just falls through to the second expression... third expression, until it reaches break.

seems like a bug in GCC to not perform consistent constraint checking.

Comment: I saw this same problem years ago using plain old C and C++ on Solaris. It's not a new thing, but more surprisingly, it's still a "problem." Live and learn I guess. Funny how "best practices" are often patterns that work around things that are anything but "best". :-)