# Objective-C Switch Statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring variables inside a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement)

I'm having difficulty getting XCode to let me write a particular switch statement in Objective-C. I'm famiiar with the syntax and could rewrite it as if/else blocks but I'm curious.

```
switch (textField.tag) {
        case kComment:
            ingredient.comment = textField.text;
            break;
        case kQuantity:
            NSLog(@""); // removing this line causes a compiler error           
            NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            fmt.generatesDecimalNumbers = true;
            NSNumber *quantity = [fmt numberFromString:textField.text];
            [fmt release]; 
            ingredient.quantity = quantity;
            break;
    }
```

I can't see the syntax error, it's as though I need to trick the compiler into allowing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can not add variable declaration after the label. You can add a semicolon instead of call to `NSLog()` for instance. Or declare variable before the switch. Or add another `{}`.

Comment: The easiest way is to put semicolon after between case and declaration .

Comment: Yes, it is sure the least number of keystrokes, but depending on the context the most esthetically pleasing solution may differ :)

Comment: That's why I've up-voted your answer :)

Comment: Here is where I say: Thank you ;-)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip. Braces are probably aesthetically best.

Comment: @Echilon, I'm often of the same opinion.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the variable declaration part within the switch statement.

Within switch statement you can't create any variable in Objective-C.

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = nil;
NSNumber *quantity = nil;
switch (textField.tag) {
        case kComment:
            ingredient.comment = textField.text;
            break;
        case kQuantity:
            fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            fmt.generatesDecimalNumbers = true;
            quantity = [fmt numberFromString:textField.text];
            [fmt release]; 
            ingredient.quantity = quantity;
            break; 
    }
```

Try this...

Comment: It appears you can -- and I don't see why not. on the second line in a switch statement, declaration works. Even if the first line is just ';'