# Why is NSString initWithFormat not working. Error "Expected expression"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, switch-statement

I have following code

```
NSString * myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
```

But in Xcode I have red exclamation with "Expected expression".

I have solved problem with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number is not from 1 to 6. randomNumber is %d", randomNumber]
```

But I  want to  know what is the problem.

Image
[http://imgur.com/iICMhYc&S7QwhFT#1](https://imgur.com/iICMhYc&S7QwhFT#1)[image]

Thanks

Comment: Yes same is happening with me. can you please post some code

Comment: @Dinesh when I comment that line everything is working, when it is uncommented that I have this error. I really do not understand why ???

Comment: Post more code, because this single line is correct.

Comment: please check your previous lines of code

Comment: please send more code/ screenshot of the error so that we also come to know what is causing the error. As the code given by you is absolutely correct

Comment: Post (copy/paste) the exact error.

Comment: The image you just included doesn't show an error message (that I can see).

Comment: @Hot fixed, it was second image, first time using this service :-)

Comment: FYI - Do not needlessly use `stringWithFormat:`. That like should just be: `NSString *myStr = @"";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In according to the Objective-C rules, if you declare an object inside a `case` of a `switch` you have to surround all the case body with brackets `{}`.

```
switch(randomNumber){
   case 1:{
      break;
   }
   default:{
      NSString * myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question being asked, chances are OP had a syntax error above or below this line and Xcode placed the error on it.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly. I have putted {} inside the default and the error is gone. So that was the problem. Any explanation why ?

Comment: Read [Declaring variables inside a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement) The problem is that `case` is a label and according with the language rules you can't put a declaration as first line of a label.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! Without it, it seems to to confuse the syntax parser :D

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 default:{
       NSString * myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
       break;
    }
```

same with `case`, if you want define instance in switch, add `{...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a variable in a `switch` statement unless you enclose the `case/default` body in `{}`.

Note that the reason for this is that a `switch` is one long block of code and the variable appears to be declared within it, but may not be initialized along all possible paths.  You'd get the same error if you declared a variable after a label that is the target of a `goto` (and note that a `switch` is just a formalized goto-label setup).