# Why can't I create an variable in an switch block?

Tags: objective-c

Strange:

```
switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        int x = 5; // error: "Expected expression before int"

        break;
}
```

So it isn't possible to create a local variable in an switch-case-block?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare variables inside an Objective-C switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115304/can-i-declare-variables-inside-an-objective-c-switch-statement)

Comment: Does it work if you make the case an actual block? like in `case foo: { int x = 5; ... }`? Remember that `switch/case` in C is just a razor-thin wrapper around a few jump targets and nothing else. That's why Duff's device is so ingenious as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try adding curly braces?

```
switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            int x = 5; // error: "Expected expression before int"

            break; 
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare a new scope for some reason. My C isn't good enough to know.

Comment: It is an oddity from the C standard.  There is some weird syntactical edge case [that I'm perpetually running into] that prevents the compiler from "just working".