# Issue with NSString and concatenation

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

Why this code gives me the following errors?

> "use of undeclared identifier baseURL"

and

> "Unexpected Interface name NSString, expected expression"

here is the entire block of code

```
switch (type) {
    case 1:
        NSString *baseURL = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.myserver.net/somephp/"];
        NSString *finalURL = [baseURL stringByAppendingString:@"?i="];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSString *finalURL = [baseURL stringByAppendingString:@"?n="];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: That code works perfectly. Are you creating an other instances with the same variable name? Can you post any other code relative to this error?

Comment: Is this within a `switch` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like those lines are within a `switch` statement. If this is the case, move the declaration of the strings outside the `switch` statement.

```
NSString *baseURL;
NSString *finalURL;
switch (<expression>) {
    case <constant>:
        baseURL = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.myserver.net/somephp"];
        finalURL = [baseURL stringByAppendingString:@"?i="];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

More information and other techniques to work around this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115304/can-i-declare-variables-inside-an-objective-c-switch-statement).