# Funny switch error in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, switch-statement

Could you try those two codes ? The first one raises an error, not the second one. I'd like to know if it's because of my XCode version, and if not, why is it happening.

```
        int typeNumber = 4;
        switch (typeNumber) {
            case typeNumberEvent:
                NSString myString;
                break;
            case typeNumberAd:
                NSURL myURL;
                break;
            default:
                NSNumber myNumber;
                break;
        }

        int typeNumber = 4;
        switch (typeNumber) {
            case typeNumberEvent:
                NSLog(@"hello");
                NSString myString;
                break;
            case typeNumberAd:
                NSLog(@"hello");
                NSURL myURL;
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"hello");
                NSNumber myNumber;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I hope you're writing more code than this.  The scope of those variables is pretty limited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare variables inside an Objective-C switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115304/can-i-declare-variables-inside-an-objective-c-switch-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare variables inside a case block, you should declare that block with curly braces. Your example would become:

```
    int typeNumber = 4;
    switch (typeNumber) {
        case typeNumberEvent:
            {
                NSString myString;
                break;
            }
        case typeNumberAd:
            {
                NSURL myURL;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                NSNumber myNumber;
                break;
            }
    }
```

This answer sums it up nicely, too: [Can I declare variables inside an Objective-C switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115304/can-i-declare-variables-inside-an-objective-c-switch-statement)

Answer (score 5):

*The compiler throws error if you try to create a variable at the first line of `case`*.

Just enclose the *case* block with braces. Everything will be alright.

```
case typeNumberEvent: {
        NSString myString;
        break;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. Do you know why we can't declare a variable at the first line ? Or you just know the remede ?

Comment: I don't know the reason. But, it seems, this is an intended behaviour of iOS.

Comment: I just came across this issue too - it does seem odd behaviour.  If it is 'intended behaviour', you think Xcode would give a better error warning.