# iOS: Why does NSRange always throw error "use of undeclared identifier"?

Tags: ios, nsrange

These lines of code are the problem:

```
case CostPeriodMonthly:
            NSRange days = [gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];

            [endDateComponents setDay:days.length];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
            [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
            break;
```

The first line using days is highlighted saying "Use of undeclared identifier days" but why? What do I miss here?

Comment: There should be indication in Xcode which part of the line is exactly wrong.

Comment: Yep, the first line using 'days', so [endDateComponents setDay:days.length]; and there 'days' is highlighted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do my switch cases sometime need braces in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582061/why-do-my-switch-cases-sometime-need-braces-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to declare new variables in a `case` statement, you have to enclose the statements in a `{}` block:

```
case CostPeriodMonthly: {
            NSRange days = [gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];

            [endDateComponents setDay:days.length];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
            [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
            break;
}
```

Comment: Actually it is sufficient to add a semicolon after the case label. Introducing a scope with `{ ... }` might be necessary if you compile with ARC (see the "possible duplicate").