# objective C switch problem

Tags: objective-c

My code looks like down this:

```
-(void)touchBegan:(HWPoint *)point {  
    switch (self.states) {  
        case HWDrawState:  
            HWShape *shape = [[HWShapeManager sharedInstance]  addShapeWithType:_shapeClass];  
            break;  
        case HWSelectState:  
            break;  
        case HWDeleteState:  
            break;  
        default:  
            break;  
    }  
}
```

Why is there a problem with HWShape.... ?
I got an error with it:

> "error: expected expression before
>   'HWShape'".

Why is that? Thank you very much for replys.

Comment: `states` sounds like it is an integer with multiple bit-flags. `case` does only mask if `states` is exactly equal to one of the enum values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose the definition in brackets:

```
case HWDrawState:
{
  HWShape *shape = [[HWShapeManager sharedInstance] addShapeWithType:_shapeClass];
}
break;
case ...
```

Comment: This has been explained there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement