# Storing vector in a struct C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, struct, nested

Why can't I do this:

```
struct sName {
  vector<int> x;
};
```

It takes only three pointers to store a vector, so I should be able to do this?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Please provide a small but complete example, and tell us in what way it fails.

Comment: "It takes only three pointers to store a vector" -- Whaaaaaa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372962/storing-vector-in-a-struct-c/2372987#2372987) this failed in a switch statement.  You'll need to wrap it up in an extra pair of braces:

```
int type = UNKNOWN;
switch(type)
{
  case UNKNOWN:
    cout << "try again" << endl;
    break;
  case KNOWN:
  { // Note the extra braces here...
    struct sName
    { 
      vector<int> x;
    } myVector; 
  } // and here
}
```

Alternatively, you could have already declared the structure, and are just trying to declare and initialize a local variable.  This isn't a problem unique to `struct`, it'll happen anytime you try to initialize a variable inside a case:

```
struct sName
{ 
  vector<int> x;
};

int type = UNKNOWN;
switch(type)
{
  case UNKNOWN:
    cout << "try again" << endl;
    break;
  case KNOWN:
  { // Note the extra braces here...
    sName myVector;
  } // and here
  case OTHER:
    int invalid = 0; // this will also fail without the extra pair of braces
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have seen this reason before, but why? And this works but I don't like this "work around".

Comment: @prasoon: all `case`s within a switch are in the same scope. A variable declared in any of them is in the scope of all of them, but the initialization could be skipped. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: @parasoon99: It's not a workaround -- it is leveraging the features of the language in a way that was intended and is valid.  It's just something you're not used to.  I do this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct sName {
  vector<int> x;
};

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -Wall 1.cpp
```

Compiled fine.

What seems to be the problem with your code?

Comment: When I declare a variable of this type "struct sName z" inside a switch statement, I get errors: cross initialization of 'sName z' and 'jump to case label'. Otherwise, the program works fine.

Comment: @parasoon99:  That's a totally different problem.  Create a new post with the new problem, but this time *include the compiler errors*

Comment: @John: Couldn't the OP (or anyone) just edit the question to reflect the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this. In fact, what you have above is correct and works fine (aside from the missing semicolon and potentially missing `std::` in `std::vector`). Please, rephrase your question so that it doesn't contradict itself.