# declare variable in switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

```
switch (i){
 case 'i': int i; break; } //it works


switch (i){
 case 'i': int i;i=0; break; } //it also works


switch (i){
 case 'i': int i=0; break; } //it ain't
```

Comment: @BlackBear he is not. Every `i` is in a different scope.

Comment: That code you presented will work just fine. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno the error, but this also works for me in Objective-C (strict superset of C, although I don't believe that <sup>1</sup>) and I do this **always**, even when I simply return something:

```
switch (i) {

  case 'i': { // <- curly brackets
    int i = 0; break;
  } // <- curly brackets

}
```

---

<sup>(1 Because a variable can be named `id` in C but not in Objective-C)</sup>

Comment: True. I always use Clang which always defaults to C99 so I'm used to it.