# iOS Xcode: throwing error

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I ran into strange issue

```
case 5:
        if(1==2) {NSLog(@"Here is a tmp stuff");}
        AuthenticationViewController *authVC = [[AuthenticationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthenticationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [authVC setTitle:@"Authentication"];
            //self.authViewController = authVC;
            //[authVC release];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:authVC animated:YES];

        break;
```

If i remove the useless if statement it fails to compile. I m unable to understand why?

Comment: the AuthenticationViewController is created and pushed, right?

Comment: Yes, afarnham has answered correctly. The case statement are bunch of labels are compiler is not aware of the scope. Wrapping every thing inside { } define the scope and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable in your case statement, which is illegal in C.

See the following for more info and how to solve this issue: [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)