# local scope in a switch statement - where do we break?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘break’ statement when using curly braces in switch-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374486/break-statement-when-using-curly-braces-in-switch-case)

While merging a package I came across this statement

```
switch (a)
{

case 1:
    {
        string str = "a is 1";
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    break;
case 2: ...
...

}
```

my question is does it matter if I place the break inside or outside the scope in case 1? 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278223(v=vs.60).aspx) they place outside. I tried [this](http://ideone.com/Tfp0c) and didn't see any difference. 
It makes sense to me that there is no difference but the guy with the PHD from my team said he remembers that there might be a difference but he can't remember what it is..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374486/break-statement-when-using-curly-braces-in-switch-case

Comment: I would recommend breaking outside the scope, despite it doesn't matter. For my gut feeling it seems to be the better style.

Comment: @KingsIndian Thanks. Not the first string that came to mind while googling this issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference whether you put the break inside or outside the scope.

Answer (score 1):

A `break` reached inside a `switch`block causes the next statment outside this `switch` block to execute. Therefore, it does not matter where you place the `break`, inside or outside the scope.