# error: A label can only be part of a statement

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, compiler-errors, getchar

I'm writing a brainfuck interpreter in C, and I'm having a little bit of trouble with the use of somethings I'm not used to. In brainfuck, a comma ( ,) is essentially getchar(). So I have the following code:

```
//This is just ptr
static char *ptr;

switch (command)
{
  case ',':
    *ptr=getchar(); // Here's the code causing error
    break;
}
```

gcc throws `error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement` at me when I try to compile this.

Any ideas? (Sorry about this, not so familiar with this error)

Comment: is it inside of a `switch` statement?

Comment: Show more of you code; and perhaps add a semi-colon `;` at the line in error.

Comment: Yes it's in a switch, I suppose I left that out.

Comment: Please post complete minimal example. This code has no errors.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you mean

```
*ptr = getchar();
```

instead of

```
ptr*=getchar();
```

Because `*=` means multiply the value on the left side with the value on the right side and assign this to the left value. However, you want to *dereference* `ptr` and write the result of `getchar` to that location.

---

Other than that your code compiles perfectly fine with my version of gcc (if I declare `command` somewhere), so you are obviously not showing us a complete example.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I fixed it in my code just now as well. It shows the same error.

Comment: ptr*=getchar() would give a different error:  
`error: invalid operands to binary * (have char * and int)`  
Not the one in the question.

Comment: @Karthik: Good point. But they may have been related. Otherwise, I cannot see an error in the presented code.

Comment: Terribly sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake entirely, I had previously commented out the code before it. I thought that this was the code causing the error due to me commenting out both codes at the same time, and it not causing this error. However I tried to comment out both, and now I understand why.

It was something about FILE and using my seek in a different case.

Comment: If I could have a nickel for every time I encountered a C syntax error wrapped like a christmas present inside of another syntax error, I would be a very wealthy man. C has its up, and its downs such as this.