# Switch statements and instance variable allocation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, switch-statement

I seem to be having a problem creating new local variables inside a switch statement.  I thought it was something in my class headers, but was even getting errors trying to allocate a new NSObject.  Here's my syntax:

```
-(NSArray *)charactersFromChapter:(NSInteger)number {
    NSObject *noError = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    //line above does not cause error
    NSArray *characters;
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
            //error happens in line above (Expected expression)
            characters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:obj];
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
    }
    return characters;
}
```

Comment: Note, those aren't 'ivars'. An ivar is an instance variable, something you'd declare in the header file. These are simply local variables. It sure would be nice if the C standards committee would allow the style you've attempted.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i'll amend the question

Comment: @GrahamPerks: Ivars don't need to be in the header anymore; they can be immediately after the `@implementation` line.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In a switch statement, you cannot initialize variables without setting a scope first, so to fix it, do something like this:

```
switch (some_expression) {
   case case_1:
   { // notice the brackets
       id some_obj = [MyObj new];
       break;
   }
   default:
       break; 
}
```

Comment: yep, that fixed it.  Thanks for the prompt reply. will accept answer after 10 minutes when it's allowed

Answer (score 5):

You need to either declare "obj" outside of the switch statement, or use braces as follows:

```
switch (number) {
    case 1: {
        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        //error happens in line above (Expected expression)
        characters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:obj];
        break;
    }
```

See here for more information:
[Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 1):

In switch-case you can only use expressions.

You can fix this by using something like this:

```
case 1:
{
       NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
       characters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:obj];
       break;
}
```