# How do switch statements work in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I am using switch statements in Objective-C, and when I nest a switch statement inside another switch statement, a lot of errors are being found by the compiler. So my general question is how do switch statements affect what methods I can call, and what type of behavior is causing the compiler to generate errors?

```
switch ([indexPath section]) 
{
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [infoKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CountdownFormatter *formatter = [[CountdownFormatter alloc] init];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [formatter stringForCountdownInterval:taskInfo.duration];
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [formatter stringForCountdownInterval:taskInfo.elapsedTime];
            default:
                break;
        }
        [formatter release];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = [actionsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //NSArray *segments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Low", @"Medium", @"High", nil];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = priority;
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                break;
            case 1:
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
                UISwitch *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = [detailsKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Here is where I am having issues. Why can I not declare a UISwitch inside this nested switch statement? I know I wrote [[UISwitch alloc] init] but the compiler is flagging it as an error. Any reason that would happen?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nesting switch statements. Why don't you post your code and error message so we can try to fix it?

Comment: I was trying not to just have people directly edit my code, I'd rather figure it out for myself, but clearly something is going on here of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say it any better than this answer [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92439/632339).

The issue is where/when you are declaring variables and the scope they are in.

Comment: Yea, I stumbled upon something similar. I didn't realize that was the issue. I ended up asking the wrong question, but arriving at the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> when I nest a switch statement inside another switch statement, a lot of errors are being found by the compiler

[Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/HMlLg):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    switch(x)
    {
    case 1:
       switch(y)
       {
       case 2:
         printf("Hello!\n");
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> So my general question is how do switch statements affect what methods I can call

They don't.

> and what type of behavior is causing the compiler to generate errors?

The programmer's behaviour.

**EDIT** - In response to the code you posted, without being able to compile or see what the error is I would suspect:

```
case 1:
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        UISwitch *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        break;
```

could be:

```
case 1:
{
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        UISwitch *myswitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        break;
}
```

Note the braces and the choice of naming the variable something other than a keyword.

Comment: It has to do with declaring variables inside the scope of a switch statement; basically, it is illegal to do so.

Comment: @gurooj Yes, that's why I added braces.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements have no effect whatsoever on obj-c. They're pure C constructs, and work in Obj-C exactly as they do in C. As for errors, you likely have some sort of syntactic error if you're getting compiler errors when nesting switch statements.

Comment: I'd like to think that writing a `switch` statement would have *some effect*.