# error C2361: initialization of 'found' is skipped by 'default' label

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

I have a strange error in my code below:

```
char choice=Getchar();
switch(choice)
{
case 's':
    cout<<" display tree ";
    thetree->displaytree();
    break;

case 'i':
    cout<<"  enter value to insert "<<endl;
    cin>>value;
    thetree->insert(value);
    break;
case 'f' :
    cout<< "enter value to find ";
    cin>>value;
    int found=thetree->find(value);
    if(found!=-1)
        cout<<" found  =  "<<value<<endl;
        else
            cout<< " not found " <<value <<endl;
        break;
default:
    cout <<" invalid entry "<<endl;;
    }
```

Visual Studio 2010 compiler says that:

```
1>c:\users\daviti\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2-3-4\2-3-4\2-3-4.cpp(317): error C2361: initialization of 'found' is skipped by 'default' label
1>          c:\users\daviti\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2-3-4\2-3-4\2-3-4.cpp(308) : see declaration of 'found'
```

I think that I have correctly written break and default  statements, so where is the error?

Comment: This is only an exact duplicate if you already know the answer to the problem. The cryptic "error C2361: initialization of 'found' is skipped by 'default' label" does not necessarily lead you to the question 'Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?'

Comment: i got today the same problem :) i am not a c++ professional and i couldn't know that declaring a pointer in a 'case' without curly braces is not allowed. so just a thought, if you know the answer or solution and want to share it then please share, but stop acting here like a smart ass.

Comment: @Constantin agree with 'smart ass' thing - but whom you are referencing to? :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to either enclose your `case 'f':` with a scoped brace:

```
case 'f' :
{  
    cout<< "enter value to find ";
    cin>>value;
    int found=thetree->find(value);
    if(found!=-1)
        cout<<" found  =  "<<value<<endl;
    else
        cout<< " not found " <<value <<endl;
    break;
}
```

or place the declaration of `found` outside of the `switch`

Answer (score 25):

The semantics of a `switch` are those of a `goto`: `case`s don't
introduce a new scope.  So `found` is accessible in your `default:` case
(although you don't actually access it).  Jumping over a non-trivial
initialization is illegal, so your code becomes illegal.

Given the complexity of your `case 'f':`, the best solution is probably
to factor it out into a separate function.  Failing that, you can put
the entire case in `{...}`, creating a separate scope, or forgo the
initialization, writing:

```
int found;
found = thetree->find(value);
```

(I mention this for completeness.  It is *not* the solution I would
recomment.)

Comment: Upvote for an actual explanation.

Comment: "`case`s don't introduce a new scope" - this sentence explains everything.

Comment: Not really, since if you have all usages below the definition there should be no issue regardless of scope, but my compiler still complains

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare the internal variables of `switch`'s `case` within curly braces. i.e.

```
case 'f' :
{
    ...
    int found=thetree->find(value);
    ...
}
```