# casting an object two times vs once performance

Tags: c++

This is a question of pure curiosity, I don't think the answer could cause great improvements.

Let suppose there is this tree of inheritance:

```
           A
          / \
         /   \
       AB     AC
      /\       /\
  ABB  ABC   ACB ACC
```

I have to write a function that executes differents actions basing on the object type.
I'm 100% sure that this object can only be an AC object or one of its childs.

now which code is faster:

```
 int t = getObjectType();
 A*  obj = getObject();
 switch (t) {
      case 0:
         ACB* casted_obj = static_cast<ACB*>(obj);
      case 1:
         ACC* casted_obj = static_cast<ACC*>(obj);
 }
```

or

```
 int t = getObjectType();
 A*  sup = getObject();
 AC* obj = static_cast<AC*>(sup);
 switch (t) {
      case 0:
         ACB* casted_obj = static_cast<ACB*>(obj);
      case 1:
         ACC* casted_obj = static_cast<ACC*>(obj);
 }
```

Probably C++ standards doesn't say anything about how the tree of inheritance must be managed, so the answer depends on the implementation.

Comment: Both code are *wrong*: you forgot to `break;`.

Comment: Also, [you can't declare variables in switch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/92396/912144), but we get the gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static casts are done entirely at compile time, so the performance impact will always be zero. The only type cast done at run time is `dynamic_cast`. More: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: That's not true. For example, if there are multiple base classes, then `static_cast` can change the value of the pointer.