# Errors showing in menu for application

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm getting a few errors in my main when I am using a `while` loop and a `switch` statement.  I have checked the curly braces and I can't spot the typo.  Can anybody see the problem?

```
bool menu = true;
    while(menu)// Loop to revert back to menu when choice is not compatable with options.
    {
    int selection;
    cout<< "Choice: ";
    cin>> selection;

        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<< "View Elements.";
            Array.print();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<< "Delete Element. ";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<< "Delete All Elements. ";
            //Array.clear(OrderedArray);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<< "Insert Element. ";
            //Array.Insert();
            break;
        case 5:
            cout<< "Search for Element. ";
            bool searchMenu = true;
            while(searchMenu)
            {
            int searchSelection;
            cout<< "Choice: ";
            cin>> searchSelection;

            switch(searchSelection)
            {
                case 1:
                cout<< "Linear Search. ";
                //Array.linearSearch();
                    break;

                case 2:
                cout<< "Binary Search ";
                //Array.binarySearch();
                    break;
            }

            }
            break;
        case 6:
            cout<< "Store. ";
            bool storeMenu = true;
            while(storeMenu)
            {
            int storeSelection;
            cout<< "Choice: ";
            cin>> storeSelection;

            switch(storeSelection)
            {
                case 1:
                cout<< "Write File ";
                //Array.writeFile();
                    break;

                case 2:
                cout<< "Read File ";
                //Array.readFile();
                    break;
            }
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            cout<< "Sort. ";
            Array.sort();
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "Exit.";
            cout << "Please press Enter to exit.";

        }
    }
```

These are the errors:

```
error C2360: initialization of 'searchMenu' is skipped by 'case' label  c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat - ordered array\repeat - ordered array\orderedarray.cpp    71  1   Repeat - Ordered Array

error C2360: initialization of 'storeMenu' is skipped by 'case' label   c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat - ordered array\repeat - ordered array\orderedarray.cpp    94  1   Repeat - Ordered Array

error C2360: initialization of 'searchMenu' is skipped by 'case' label  c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat - ordered array\repeat - ordered array\orderedarray.cpp    94  1   Repeat - Ordered Array

error C2360: initialization of 'storeMenu' is skipped by 'case' label   c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat - ordered array\repeat - ordered array\orderedarray.cpp    98  1   Repeat - Ordered Array

error C2360: initialization of 'searchMenu' is skipped by 'case' label  c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat - ordered array\repeat - ordered array\orderedarray.cpp    98  1   Repeat - Ordered Array`
```

Comment: `Array` looks like a class, not an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the code for a case statement gets to be longer than two or three lines, it should probably be turned into a separate function. Especially with these nested menus. The other answers are correct that the compiler is complaining about defining variables in case statements; code reviewers will complain that the switch statement is too complex.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap variable definitions inside a new block (`{ }`) inside switch statements, i.e.

```
switch (var) {
case X: {
    bool var = here;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create-initialize variables inside `case` block unless you create a local scope for them:

```
switch(Foo)
{
    case A:
    int a = 0; <== error
    break;

    case B:
    {
        int b = 0; <== ok
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Just to confuse things, `int a; a = 0;` would be okay. The issue isn't creating variables, but initializing them. Not that I'm recommending this approach...

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thanks, did know about that. +1 to your answer