# reassigning blocks objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5, objective-c-blocks

The block is a property defined in GridScrollView:

```
typedef BoxView* (^RenderBlock)(NSDictionary* json, CGRect);
@interface GridScrollView : PagingScrollView
@property (nonatomic, copy) RenderBlock renderBlock;
```

I want to use it like this:

```
switch(current.tag)
{
    case 1:
        scrollView.renderBlock = ^(NSDictionary* json, CGRect frame)
        {
             //returns a boxview
        }
        break;
     case 2:
        scrollView.renderBlock = ^(NSDictionary* json, CGRect frame)
        {
             //returns a different boxview
        }
        break;
}
```

While this code works fine the first time around, when it gets reassigned I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0) error. What's happening here?

Comment: If you have a crash, post the backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the call to the block is itself performing the declaration of an object, try adding an extra pair of braces around it:

```
case 1: {
            scrollView.renderBlock = ^(NSDictionary* json, CGRect frame) {
             //returns a boxview
            }
        }
        break;
```

Although I don't know why it would run as is the first time and then crash.

Comment: Why it works: [variables in switch statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement). As Thomas explains, it's a matter of scope. Also see MrZebra's answer, toward the bottom -- I should have said the problem was with the initialization of an object, not with its declaration.