# switch and initialization of a variable

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

I saw somethere that in C the initialization of a variable can be skipped by a jump statement, as in the following example:

```
/* valid in C but not C++ */

int main()
{
    switch (1)
    {
    case 0:
        int foo = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        ++foo;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when i try to compile it with Comeau compiler there are errors:

> "ComeauTest.c", line 8: error: a declaration cannot have a label
>             int foo = 0;
>             ^
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 5: warning: transfer of control bypasses
>   initialization of:
>               variable "foo" (declared at line 8)
>         switch (1)
>         ^

Comment: To get around that you can use the scope braces. That is put '{' before the int foo = 0 and put '}' after int foo = 0;

Comment: Yeah, i know. I want to know why i can't do it in C, while in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement all says that it's possible

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Add a semicolon after `case 0:;`. Declarations are not allowed directly after the label.