# C: wrongly nested switch/case blocks surprisingly works

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I just discovered the following section in some code I maintain:

```
switch (m) {
    case 62: { // opening
        // some declarations
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case 63:
        // do some other stuff
        break;
        }      // closing
    default:
        // default stuff
        break;
 }
```

The block opening is meant to declaring some local variables, but the closing brace is wrongly placed and occurs after the `case 63`.

I have never noticed this for months as it compiles well in Visual Studio 2010. I've tried debugging it and both cases work fine.

How can it be ? Is this correct C syntax ?

Comment: Is `case 63` reachable through the `switch`?

Comment: You may have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement). The curly-braces define scope for the variables declared inside.

Comment: @wallyk, yes! This is what surprised me.

Comment: If `case 63` did have some variable declarations, it _would_ be incorrect syntax, then. But since there isn't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**6.8.1 Labeled statements, C99**

> Any statement may be preceded by a prefix that declares an identifier
>   as a label name. **Labels in themselves do not alter the flow of
>   control, which continues unimpeded across them.**

i.e. The curly braces have no effect on how the switch-case labels work but it merely creates a new scope.

This explains why the seemingly *misplaced* curly braces don't result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 16):

The `case` statements are just like goto labels and so that is allowed syntax. [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffs_device) is a famous use-case.

Try to avoid doing it though.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, this is correct syntax per the language standard. You can even do this:

```
switch (m) break;
```

or this:

```
switch (m);
```

`case const-expr:` works pretty much like a regular label that you'd use with `goto`.