# initialization of 'element' is skipped by 'case' label

Tags: c++, debugging

I don't understand why I am getting the error:

> initialization of 'element' is skipped by 'case' label.

Can someone please explain to me?

```
void LinkedList::process_example(int choice) {
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        cout << endl << endl << "Current S = ";
        this->printSet();

        cout << "Enter an element :";
        char* element = "lol";

        //cin>>element;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(200, '\n');

        this->Addelementfromback(element); //error is here
        cout << endl << endl << "Current S = ";

        this->printSet();
        break;

    case 2:
        this->check_element();
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Current Set S = ";
        this->printSet();

        cout << endl << "S has ";
        int count = this ->check_cardinality();
        cout << count << " elements";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is pretty clear, also very odd use of a switch statement.

Comment: Each `case` does not introduce a new scope (only `{ }` blocks do that). So when you declare a variable inside one case, it should put be within its own block.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try wrap `case` with `{}`, and put all your statement inside `{}`.

```
case 1:
{
   cout << endl << endl << "Current S = ";
   this->printSet();    
   // and other mess
}
break;
```

You should put all these statement in functions, keep `case` statement clear. For example, write this style:

```
case 1:
   initializeElement();
   break;
case 2:
   doSomethingElse();
   break;
```

See  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: @billiz why does putting the {   } solve the problem???

Comment: scope issue, `case:` doesn't introduce new scope till `break`, so you have to use `{}`

Comment: I still dont quite understand , any article i can read to better understand???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 15):

When a variable is declared in one `case`, the next `case` is technically still in the same scope so you could reference it there but if you hit that `case` without hitting this one first you would end up calling an uninitialised variable. This error prevents that.

All you need to do is either define it before the `switch` statement or use curly braces `{ }` to make sure it goes out of scope before exiting a specific `case`.