# Why do case statements only accept constants?

Tags: c++, c++11, switch-statement

What is the reason behind the fact thet switch statements in C++ have to be written with constants?

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
switch(variable)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        //Code 1
        break;

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        //Code 2
        break;

    default:
        //Code 3
        break;
}
```

In other languages, for example PAWN (C-Like scripting language), I could write this code down as such:

```
switch(variable)
{
    case 1 .. 4:
        //Code 1
        break;

    case 5 .. 8:
        //Code 2
        break;

    default:
        //Code 3
        break;
}
```

What is the reason behind the fact the C++ switch statement is soo.. from the Stone Age? (Not to mention we can't use variables.)

Even after so many changes and updates over all those years...

Comment: It's hard to create a jump table at runtime? The ranges thing is kind of a separate deal. Perhaps if that syntax ever makes it in (I do personally find it somewhat nice; it's in D as well), the proposal to add it to switches wouldn't be long after, but it might need some extra work to keep in line with the `switch` syntax.

Comment: What does that PAWN syntax have to do with forcing constants? Is `1 .. 4` not a constant? (also, make a macro `SEQ(1, 4)`)

Comment: @Pubby, Interesting idea. I don't dabble around with preprocessor black magic that much, but could `BOOST_PP_FOR` do that?

Comment: It's the way the language is defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: That question is about a different issue.

Comment: It's not really constructive asking why a language doesn't have a feature. Even if the conclusion is that it should be added, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: That's a little fatalistic. If there is a large enough consensus that language X needs feature Y, sometimes it can happen. Witness lambdas in C++!

Comment: @StilesCrisis True, but since the standardization process takes several years, "Propose an addition to the standard" is not a practical solution, since your project is typically due sooner.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the OP where he is time-constrained on this issue or has a project due on a date. (Anyway, it can be emulated or faked any number of ways.) He is just wondering why the language doesn't have ranged `case`s. It's a totally valid question IMO.

Answer (score 5):

There's no technical reason that C switch statements couldn't be updated to use ranges. gcc already has an extension for this.

http://www.n4express.com/blog/?p=1225

There are good reasons for the values to be *constant*; that allows for all sorts of optimizations such as jump tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind another lookup, you could generate a table to simplify your case statement:

```
char the_case (unsigned variable) {
    static const char all_cases[] = {
        0,
        'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
        'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
    };
    if (variable < sizeof(all_cases)) return all_cases[variable];
    return 0;
}

//...
switch (the_case(variable)) {
case 'A':
    //...
    break;
case 'B':
    //...
    break;
default:
    //...
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an `unordered_map` to function pointers or methods, where the key is your `variable` type.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` was designed for a simple table-lookup, as was the Pascal `case`. The Pascal `case` supported ranges, with, as I recall, the same notation as for Pascal bitsets. C could have done likewise, but for whatever reasons, didn't.

And there's just not been sufficient demand for that feature to make it into either standard, C or C++.

Regarding variables or non-integral types for the case labels, that would change the nature of the statement. C and C++ simply do not *have* a general `select` statement. But in C++ you can cook it up yourself:

```
template< class Key >
auto select(
    const Key&                          key,
    const map<Key, function<void()>>&   actions
    )
    -> bool
{
    const auto it = actions.find( key );
    if( it == actions.end() ) { return false; }
    it->second();  return true;
}
```

And then you can write things like

```
auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Command? ";
    const string command = readline();
    select( command, map<string, function<void()>>
    {
        { "blah", []{ cout << "You said blah!\n"; } },
        { "asd",  []{ cout << "You said asd!?!\n"; } }
    } );
}
```

You can easily add a default to that if you want, e.g. by using the `or` keyword.

Hm, funny I didn't think of that before, but then apparently neither did anyone else. :)