# How can I use NSBundle in Switch Case of Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I entered the following things, but there are some errors shown, which is expected expression in the line after case 0, and use of undeclared identifiers "bundle". Could anyone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc ]init];
            NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"HK" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            break;            
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"case 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"case 2");
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"case 3");
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"case 4");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some brackets so that the compiler knows what scope to apply:

```
case 0:
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"HK" ofType:@"plist"];
    placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    break; 
}
```

Also, don't use `alloc init` on `NSBundle`. You either want to get the `mainBundle` (as above) or specifically get some other bundle in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable declaration on the first line of the `case` block. Wrap the block in braces:

```
case 0:
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc ]init];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"HK" ofType:@"plist"];
    placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    break;
}
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

is the correct way.