# Error in switch statement in my code. (c++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have an error with my switch statement in this baseball calculator. The error says :"    transfer of control bypasses initialization of:"

The switch statement is used for the types of calculations you want to do in this program like:

On base percentage 
Batting Average 
etc...

```
// Baseball Stat.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
char menu_choice;
// Batting average formula.

float b_average(float hits, float bats) {return hits/bats;};

// On base percentage formula

float OBP(float hits, float walks, float Hit_by_Pitch, float bats, float sac_flys) {return (hits+walks+Hit_by_Pitch) / (bats+walks+Hit_by_Pitch+sac_flys);};

// Strikeout Ratio Formula 

float Strikeout_ratio(float strikeouts, float bats) {return strikeouts/bats;};

// Fielding Average Formula 

float fielding_average(float putouts, float assists, float errors) {return (putouts+assists) / (putouts + assists+errors);};

// Range Factor Formula

float range_factor(float putouts , float assists, float defins) {return (putouts+assists) * 9 / defins;};

// Pythagorean Expectation Formula

float pyt_expectation(double runs, double runs_allowed) {return (pow(runs, 1.83) / (pow(runs, 1.83) + pow(runs_allowed, 1.83))) * 100;};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    cout << "BASEBALL STATISTICS CALCULATOR\n";
    cout << "\nWhat do you want to calculate?\n""\nA.BATTING AVERAGE\n""\nB.ON BASE PERCENTAGE (OBP)\n""\nC.STRIKEOUT RATIO\n""\nD.FIELDING AVERAGE\n""\nE.RANGE FACTOR\n""\nF.BASEBALL GAME SIMULATOR\n";
    cin >> menu_choice;
```

here's the error:

```
    switch(menu_choice)
    {
    case 'A':

        // Variables for First Player's Batting Average.
        int atBatsBA;
        int numHitsBA;
        // Variables for Second Player's Batting Average.
        int second_atBatsBA;
        int second_numHitsBA;

        cout << "\nBATTING AVG\n\n";
        cout << "Player #1 At bats:\n";
        cin >> atBatsBA;
        cout << "Player #1 Hits:\n";
        cin >> numHitsBA;

        cout << "Player #2 At Bats:\n";
        cin >> second_atBatsBA;
        cout << "Player #2 Hits:\n";
        cin >> second_numHitsBA;


        cout << "\nPlayer #1's Batting Average is:\n" << b_average(numHitsBA, atBatsBA) << endl;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2's Batting Average is:\n" << b_average(second_numHitsBA, second_atBatsBA) << endl;

        break;

    case 'B':

        // Variables for First Player's OBP
        int atBatsOBP;
        int hitsOBP;
        int walksOBP; 
        int Hit_By_PitchOBP; 
        int sa_flysOBP;

        // Variables for Second Player's OBP
        int second_atBatsOBP;
        int second_hitsOBP;
        int second_walksOBP;
        int second_Hit_By_PitchOBP;
        int second_sa_flysOBP;



        cout << "\nOBP PERCENTAGE\n";
        cout << "\nPlayer #1 At bats:\n";
        cin >> atBatsOBP;
        cout << "Player #1 Hits:\n";
        cin >> hitsOBP;
        cout << "Player #1 Walks:\n";
        cin >> walksOBP;
        cout << "Player #1 Hits by Pitch:\n";
        cin >> Hit_By_PitchOBP;
        cout << "Player #1 Sac Flys:\n";
        cin >> sa_flysOBP;
        cout << "Player #2 At bats:\n";
        cin >> second_atBatsOBP;
        cout << "Player #2 Hits:\n";
        cin >> second_hitsOBP;
        cout << "Player #2 Walks:\n";
        cin >> second_walksOBP;
        cout << "Player #2 Hits by Pitch:\n"; 
        cin >> second_Hit_By_PitchOBP;
        cout << "Player #2 Sac Flys:\n";
        cin >> second_sa_flysOBP;

        cout << "\nPlayer #1's OBP:\n" << OBP(hitsOBP,walksOBP,Hit_By_PitchOBP,atBatsOBP,sa_flysOBP) << endl;  
        cout << "\nPlayer #2's OBP:\n" << OBP(second_hitsOBP,second_walksOBP,second_Hit_By_PitchOBP,second_atBatsOBP,second_sa_flysOBP) << endl;

        break;

    case 'C':

        // Variables for First Player's Strikeout Ratio 

        int atBatsSOR;
        int strikeoutsSOR;
        // Variables for Second Player's Strikeout Ratio 

        int second_atBatsSOR;
        int second_strikeoutsSOR;

        cout << "\nSTRIKEOUT RATION\n";
        cout << "\nPlayer #1 At bats:\n";
        cin >> atBatsSOR;
        cout << "\nPlayer #1 Strikeouts:\n";
        cin >> strikeoutsSOR;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2 At bats:\n";
        cin >> second_atBatsSOR;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2 Strikeouts:\n";
        cin >> second_strikeoutsSOR;

        cout << "\nPlayer #1's Strikeout Ratio:\n" << Strikeout_ratio(strikeoutsSOR,atBatsSOR) << endl;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2's Strikeout Ratio:\n" << Strikeout_ratio(second_strikeoutsSOR,second_atBatsSOR) << endl;

        break;

    case'D':

        // Variables for First Player's Fielding Average.

        int putoutsFA;
        int assistsFA;
        int errorsFA;

        // Variables for Second Player's Fielding Average.

        int second_putoutsFA;
        int second_assistsFA;
        int second_errorsFA;

        cout << "\nFIELDING AVERAGE\n";
        cout << "\nPlayer #1's putouts:\n";
        cin >> putoutsFA;
        cout << "Player #1's assists:\n";
        cin >> assistsFA;
        cout << "Player #1's errors:\n";
        cin >> errorsFA;
        cout << "Player #2's putouts:\n";
        cin >> second_putoutsFA;
        cout << "Player #2's assists:\n";
        cin >> second_assistsFA;
        cout << "Player #2's errors:\n";
        cin >> second_errorsFA;


        cout << "\nPlayer #1's Fielding Average:\n" << fielding_average(putoutsFA, assistsFA, errorsFA) << endl;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2's Fielding Average:\n" << fielding_average(second_putoutsFA, second_assistsFA, second_errorsFA) << endl;

        break;

    case 'E':

        // Variables for First Player's Range Factor.

        int putoutsRF;
        int assistsRF;
        int defensive_inningsRF;

        // Variables for Second Player's Range Factor.

        int second_putoutsRF;
        int second_assistsRF;
        int second_defensive_inningsRF;


        cout << "\nRANGE FACTOR\n";
        cout << "\nPlayer #1's putouts:\n";
        cin >> putoutsRF;
        cout << "Player #1's assists:\n";
        cin >> assistsRF;
        cout << "Player #1's Defensive Innings Played:\n";
        cin >> defensive_inningsRF;
        cout << "Player #2's putouts:\n";
        cin >> second_putoutsRF;
        cout << "Player #2's assists:\n";
        cin >> second_assistsRF;
        cout << "Player #2's Defensive Innings Played:\n";
        cin >> second_defensive_inningsRF;


        cout << "\nPlayer #1's Range Factor:\n" << range_factor(putoutsRF, assistsRF, defensive_inningsRF) << endl;
        cout << "\nPlayer #2's Range Factor:\n" << range_factor(second_putoutsRF, second_assistsRF, second_defensive_inningsRF) << endl;

        break;

    case'F':

        // Variables for first team's batting average.
        string ftname;
        int atbatsTBA;
        int hitsTBA;

        // Variables for second team's batting average.
        string stname;
        int second_atbatsTBA;
        int second_hitsTBA;


        cout << "\nBASEBALL GAME SIMULATOR\n";
        cout << "\nPlease enter the first team's name:\n";
        cin >> ftname;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the second team's name:\n";
        cin >> stname;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the first teams' total at bats:\n";
        cin >> atbatsTBA;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the first teams's total hits:\n";
        cin >> hitsTBA;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the second team's total at bats:\n";
        cin >> second_atbatsTBA;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the second team's total hits:\n";
        cin >> second_hitsTBA;

        cout << "\n" << ftname << " 's Batting Average is:\n" << b_average(atbatsTBA, hitsTBA) << "\n";
        cout << "\n" << stname << " 's Batting Average is:\n" << b_average(second_atbatsTBA, second_hitsTBA) << "\n";

        int TBA;
        int TBA2;
        TBA = b_average(atbatsTBA, hitsTBA);
        TBA2 = b_average(second_atbatsTBA, second_hitsTBA);

        if(TBA>TBA2){

            cout << ftname <<" Wins!!\n";

        }
        else if(TBA<TBA2){

            cout << stname << " Wins!!\n";

        }
        else{

            cout << "It's a draw!!\n";

        }
        break;

    default :

        cout << "Please enter a valid option\n";

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/): kind of like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=07aa468dfa24a6dba821463d1fd0b459-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare variables inside of switch cases unless you add a new scope. Just change each of your cases to look like this instead:

```
case 'X': {
  // original contents
} break;
```

That will allow you to declare new variables inside the scope delimited by the `{}`s and avoid this error.

Comment: Or change each of the cases to call a function. There's far too much code in each branch.