# Using {} in a case statement. Why?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

What is the point with using `{` and `}` in a `case` statement? Normally, no matter how many lines are there in a `case` statement, all of the lines are executed. Is this just a rule regarding older/newer compilers or there is something behind that?

```
int a = 0;
switch (a) {
  case 0:{
    std::cout << "line1\n";
    std::cout << "line2\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

and

```
int a = 0;
switch (a) {
  case 0:
    std::cout << "line1\n";
    std::cout << "line2\n";
    break;
}
```

Comment: One use can be to limit the scope of variables declared in the case statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: Too much indentation, too. The cases are just labels within the switch statement's block: they don't introduce additional nesting, so they should align with the `switch` keyword, and in the second example, the enclosed statements only indented once. Note how you have an awkward four space de-indent after the `break;`.

Comment: Note, the accepted answer is only partially correct as [Jack's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031147/using-in-a-case-statement-why#comment29856700_20031179) points out and misses some subtleties, which I address in my answer.

Comment: Just as an FYI: in C (even C11) rather than C++, you cannot label a declaration; they are not in the syntactic category `statement`. In C++, you can (one component of the syntactic category `statement` is `declaration statement`).

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The `{}` denotes a new block of **scope**.

Consider the following very contrived example:

```
switch (a)
{
    case 42:
        int x = GetSomeValue();
        return a * x;
    case 1337:
        int x = GetSomeOtherValue(); //ERROR
        return a * x;
}
```

You will get a compiler error because `x` is already defined in the scope.

Separating these to their own sub-scope will eliminate the need to declare `x` outside the switch statement.

```
switch (a)
{
    case 42: {
        int x = GetSomeValue();
        return a * x; 
    }
    case 1337: {
        int x = GetSomeOtherValue(); //OK
        return a * x; 
    }
}
```

---

Warning:

Declare and initialize a variable inside `case` without `{}` surrounded is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int b = 3;
    switch (b) {
    case 3:
        int a = 3; //compilation error: "initialization of 'a' skipped by 'case' label"
        return a * b;
    case 1:
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually IMO you will get a compiler error even if you skip the second declaration of variable x.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: You should not be getting an error, though if `case 1337:` still `return a * x;` then you should be getting a warning that `x` may be uninitialized.

Comment: Although over using this style and putting big blocks inside the switch statement will make it unreadable to follow the cases. I prefer to keep the statements tiny.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know for a fact that MS Visual Studio 2010 will have the behavior Abhishek indicates: it will not compile any variable declaration inside a case (unless you use curly brackets to denote a new scope within that case). Whether that matches the standards, I don’t know.

Comment: @KRyan: it does not, but it's such a much safer alternative that I can hardly blame them for enforcing this.

Comment: Using or omitting `{ }` is a matter of personal style, yet one still has to watch out for putting either `break` or `return`. I wonder if K&R (C lang creators) were happy with their decision of default fallthrough behavior with explicit breaks, instead of choosing deafult non-fallthrough with explicit activation of fallthrough.

Comment: Section 6.7(3) of the standard (numbering for the 2005 draft) specifies that you cannot jump an initialisation, so you cannot have initialisation in a case block.

Comment: @JackAidley is correct here, although you basically have the concept, your example and explanation are not correct. It is never okay to jump over a declaration with an initialization, so the code would be an error regardless of the second declaration of `x`. See my answer for the details.

Comment: @MatthieuM. jumping a declaration with an initialization is a violation of the standard and both `gcc` and `clang` do not allow it and I would be surprised if visual studio did.

Comment: @Shafik I never claimed that in the absence of the declaration the code would be fine, just that in my example, the declaration is where the error would be.

Comment: That is a confusing example, at least two other users felt the need to comment on that so it is clearly not obvious and it misses the whole concept that jumping a declaration with an initialization is not valid code, which would probably confuse a novice user trying to learn something from this code example. At least you should remove the initialization from the declaration.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm usually very accepting of suggestions and criticism but I am having trouble understanding how the example is unclear. It is only there to show invalid code in which adding `{` and `}` to each case will produce valid code. I've omitted the version with `{` and `}` because it's repetitive and redundant.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: It depends whether the diagnosis is mandatory; some languages that are ill-formed (for example wrt. the One Definition Rules) require no diagnosis, just because sometime it is expensive/difficult to perfectly detect the cases reliably. And I know not whether it is.

Comment: A less contrived example might show reliance on scoping for object lifetimes rather than name scope, i.e. if some cases, but not all, need a scoped mutex lock.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I agree with you ;). I think the concept of jumping a declaration with an initialization is not valid code should be mentioned in this answer. And the first code snippet could be misleading indeed.

Answer (score 25):

**TL;DR**

The only way you can declare a variable with an intializer or some non-trivial object inside a *case* is to introduce a *block scope* using `{}` or other control structure that has it's own scope like a *loop* or *if statement*.

**Gory details**

We can see that *cases* are just *labeled statements* like the *labels* used with a *goto* statement(*this is covered in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section 6.1 Labeled statement*) and we can see from section `6.7` paragraph *3* that jumping pass a declaration is not allowed in many cases, including those with an initialization:

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps<sup>87</sup> from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

and provides this example:

```
void f() {
 // ...
 goto lx; // ill-formed: jump into scope of a

 ly:
  X a = 1;
 // ...
 lx:
  goto ly; // OK, jump implies destructor
          // call for a followed by construction
          // again immediately following label ly
}
```

Note, there are some subtleties here, you are allowed to jump past a *scalar declaration* that does not have an initialization, for example:

```
switch( n ) 
{
    int x ;
    //int x  = 10 ; 
    case 0:
      x = 0 ;
      break;
    case 1:
      x = 1 ;
      break;
    default:
      x = 100 ;
      break ;
}
```

is perfectly valid(*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed1a05e9b6c612ce)*). Of course if you want to declare the same variable in each *case* then they will each need their own scope but it works the same way outside of *switch* statements as well, so that should not be a big surprise.

As for the rationale for not allowing jump past initialization, [defect report 467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#467) although covering a slightly different issue provides a reasonable case for *automatic variables*:

> [...]automatic variables, if not explicitly initialized, can have indeterminate (“garbage”) values, including trap representations, [...]

It is probably more interesting to look at the case where you extend a scope within a *switch* over multiple *cases* the most famous examples of this is probably [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) which would look something like this:

```
void send( int *to, const int *from, int  count)
{
        int n = (count + 7) / 8;
        switch(count % 8) 
        {
            case 0: do {    *to = *from++;   // <- Scope start
            case 7:         *to = *from++;
            case 6:         *to = *from++;
            case 5:         *to = *from++;
            case 4:         *to = *from++;
            case 3:         *to = *from++;
            case 2:         *to = *from++;
            case 1:         *to = *from++;
                        } while(--n > 0);    // <- Scope end
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is a habit that allows you to inject variable declarations with the resulting destructor (or scope conflicts) into `case` clauses.  Another way of looking at it is they are writing for the language they wish they had, where all flow control consists of blocks and not sequences of statements.

Answer (score 4):

Check this a basic compiler restriction and you will start wondering whats happening  :

```
int c;
c=1;

switch(c)
{
    case 1:
    //{
        int *i = new int;
        *i =1;
        cout<<*i;
        break;
    //}

    default : cout<<"def";
}
```

This will give you an error:

```
error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
error:   crosses initialization of ‘int* i’
```

While this one will not:

```
int c;
c=1;

switch(c)
{
    case 1:
    {
        int *i = new int;
        *i =1;
        cout<<*i;
        break;
    }

    default : cout<<"def";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using brackets in switch denotes a new block of scope as said by Rotem.

But it can be as well for clarity when you read. To know where the case stops as you might have conditionnal break in it.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons might be:

1. Readability, it visually enhances each case as a scoped section.
2. Declaring the a different variables with the same name for several switch cases.
3. Micro optimizations- scope for a really expensive resource allocated variable that you want to destruct as soon as you leave the scope of the case, or even a more spaghetti scenario of the "GOTO" command usage.