# Fork() defining variable

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to implement the code below, but it gives me errors here:

```
char **lines = tokenizer(buffer, "\n"); //use of undeclared identifier 'lines'
free(lines); //use of undeclared identifier 'lines'
```

Actual code piece:

```
int child = fork();
switch (child) {
    case 0 :
        // child process
        char **lines = tokenizer(buffer, "\n");
        free(lines);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: add error message and your tokenizer function

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - to share variable between child and parent is not that easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are compiling it with a `C` compiler but use `C++` syntax.

Try this:

```
{
    char **lines = tokenizer(buffer, "\n");
    free(lines);
}
```

As a note - if you try to share variable and populate it from a child process - this will not work.

Comment: What is the c syntax for this?

Comment: What was the problem I don't get it. It just worked now

Comment: Just open a block of `{ ... }`. In `C` You can declare variables inside a scope only after its beginning

Answer (score 1):

A declaration is not permitted immediately after a `case` statement. There are three possble fixes:

- Enclose the code after the `case` in braces: `case 0: { char **line = ...}`.
- Move the declaration to just after the `switch`:

  ```
   switch (child) {
       char **lines;
       case 0:
           lines = tokenizer(buffer, "\n");
  ```
- Or, surprisingly, just add an extra `;` after the `case` statement:

  ```
   switch (child) {
       case 0:
           ;
           char **lines = tokenizer(buffer, "\n");
  ```

See [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement).

Comment: because I want them just in my child process