# C++11: Declare variable within switch statement

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, switch-statement, definition

I know that C++03 doesn't allow to define variables within switch block without using 
curly braces.

```
const int i = ...
switch (i) { case 0: int j = 0; break; } // 1. error here
switch (i) { case 0: { int j = 0; } break; } // 2. ok
```

What is regarding new C++11 standard?
Does it allow first form?
Can I also write something like this:

```
switch (i) 
{ 
  case 0: int j = 0; break; 
  case 1: int j = 0; break; 
  case 2: int j = 0; break; 
}
```

Comment: Nah, still gotta use a block. Also, your first example is slightly confusing, just FYI.

Comment: What's the error in the first example? Looks fine to me. Or did you mean to use `i` everywhere, instead of `i` and `j`?

Comment: I just wanted to say that we have selector - i and define another variable named distictly - j

Answer (score 4):

The `case` statement did not (in C++03) and still does not (in C++11) introduce a scope.

The standard says in `[stmt.switch]` (6.4.2/6):

> case and default labels in themselves do not alter the flow of
>   control, which continues unimpeded across such labels.

Thus it is allowed to "fall through" `case` statements like this:

```
int x, a = 1;
switch(a) {
case 1:
    x = 5;
    // no break here!
case 10:
    x *= 4; // x is now 20.
}
```

If you would introduce a varible declaration for example below the first `case` statement, it could be skipped when a jump to the second `case` statement would happen.

You can however declare a local variable right at the start of the `switch` block:

```
switch (i) 
{
    int j;
case 0: j = 0; break; 
case 1: j = 0; break; 
case 2: j = 0; break; 
}
```

A `switch` is really more a jump table than a series of `if`/`else if` statements.

Comment: I never knew you could declare variables before the first case label.

Comment: @MarkRansom You can have pretty much anything there (`switch (3) { puts("Huh?!"); }`), which is almost never useful, but a variable declaration is one of the few exceptions where it is useful.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Something else similar, interesting, and perhaps surprising that one can do with a switch statement is a [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device). It's worth a look if you've never seen it. Essentially you interleave the body of the a loop with the body of the switch in order to unroll a loop while skipping some variable amount of the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

C++03 certainly allows you to define variables within the body of a switch statement. That body is not at all different from any other compound statement, the rules for jumping to a label apply the same way: you can only jump into scope of

- scalar types declared without initializers
- class types with trivial default constructors and trivial destructors declared without initializers
- arrays of the above

these rules didn't change in C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    switch(n)
    {
               int a;      // okay, scalar with no initializer
       case 1: int b = 10; // okay, no more labels, no way jump into scope
               a = b = 3*n;
               break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write this because of scope problem. Your code will lead to a redefinition of the variable `j`

In your code :

```
const int i = ...
switch (i) { case 0: int j = 0; break; } // the error should be linked to default statement that is not there
switch (i) { case 0: { int j = 0; } break; } // here  you define a local scope in which you can define `j` ; j will be destroyed after the closing bracket.
```

Even in c++11, trying to do this :

```
switch (i) 
{ 
  case 0: int j = 0; break; 
  case 1: int j = 0; break; 
  case 2: int j = 0; break; 
}
```

lead to the same error than if you want to write :

```
for ( ; ; ) {
      int i = 0 ;
      int i = 0 ;
      int i = 0 ;
}
```

That will lead to a redefinition error

Comment: That is not the reason this is forbidden, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement) for the real reason (jumping over initialization).