# Method can't be used within Switch statement?

Tags: ios, switch-statement

How come I can't use `sceneWithSize:` inside a switch statement? If I create an object of my new game scene outside the switch case it works fine? But I\m switching game scenes depending on which `spriteNode` the user selected. Why is this happening and is there an alternative method to do what I'm trying to do?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      /* Called when a touch begins */
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        NSLog(@"Level Selected: %@", node.name);
        int x = [node.name intValue];

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                 // if I move this code outside the switch statement it works?
                LevelOne *newscene = [LevelOne sceneWithSize:self.size]; // here is where I get an expected expression error?
                 //[self.view presentScene:newscene transition:[SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:1]];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not because of the method call, it's because you can't start a `case` with a variable declaration. You have to wrap the whole block in curly braces, like this:

```
switch (x) {
        case 1: {
             // if I move this code outside the switch statement it works?
            LevelOne *newscene = [LevelOne sceneWithSize:self.size]; // here is where I get an expected expression error?
             //[self.view presentScene:newscene transition:[SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:1]];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Technical explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: whoops thanks I blame Xcode's default code snippet for a switch case statement :P