# Declaring a variable inside loop but using it out side?

Tags: c++

As the title suggest how can i declare a variable inside loop and use it outside?

**EXAMPLE**

```
void Function(String s)
{
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
            case 'i':int x;
            case 'd':double x;
            case 'c':char x;
        }//end of switch
    }//end of for loop

    //now i want to use 'x' here,i.e.,out side the loop how will i do it?

}//end of void function
```

**EDIT** I know the scope thing but i saw some one achieving this with template class/function but I dont know how to use template class/func to do this..so anyone knows?

Comment: It is quite simple: you can't.

Comment: ...so define it outside of the loop. And if you want to save memory by not defining the types you won´t need, use a union. The switch only sets some type-flag what to use...

Comment: OK i know the scope thing... Thats why i asked this question ._. but i see somewhere that some one did it using template class/func but idk how to use template class/func to achieve this so anyone knows?

Comment: @Zeus Maybe show us the code after the loop and we can suggest an alternative option. The answer could very well involve templates but without seeing how you *use* `x` we can't know.

Comment: read the edit i made pls

Comment: @Zeus - Your comments about your last question are irrelevant for this question. Grind you axes elsewhere.

Comment: @Zues - this should cause a compiler error: `case 'i':int x;`. How does that code even compile?

Comment: Well, you can do it by implementing your own compiler (one which violates the C++ language standard).

Comment: @jww I see no reason that line wouldn't compile. However, when it runs into `case 'd':double x;` it should complain that `x` already exists.

Comment: @Zeus Your edit still doesn't show us the code you want to write after the loop. I need to see that in order to help you turn it into a template.

Comment: @cdhowdie - see [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/92396/608639)

Comment: -jww No need to be rude..   @cdhowie i will edit topic in few mins

Comment: @Zeus - I don't quite follow you. What are you talking about?

Comment: this is probably a x-y problem, but have a look at boost::any

Comment: So, basically, you want ONE variable name to represent different types? Generally, C and C++ has a strict 1:1 relationship between type and name, you can't "change" that based on control flow in the code. The solution is to use for example a `union` or some other type of wrapping the type you actually want inside something.

Comment: OK Problem solved i achieved the thing i was trying to do with std::map with struct, a big THANKS to all those tried to help @cdhowie Thnx, u asked for code so i began to write the program and while doing it i faced another problem so googled it and came across std::map with struct which solved my prob..

Answer (score 0):

`{` `}` - are scope delimiters, anything you define inside it, cannot be access outside. So if you want, you can declare it outside loop and then you can access it outside as well as inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

No. Simplified, that's  what a scope is - the scope within which declared variables are accessible.

You need to declare the variable in the outer scope if you want to access it from there:

```
{
   int x = 0;
   for (...)
   {
       x= 1;
   }
   if (x ==1)
   {
       printf("it works");
   }
}
```