# c++ Declaring a variable inside a switch statement

Tags: c++, scope, switch-statement, variable-declaration

I have a `switch` statement in my C++ code, and want to declare and use a variable inside a `case` of that statement. The variable will only be used inside the scope of that particular `case`.

```
switch(mode)
{
case abc:
    ...
    struct commonData;
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    int someInt = 1;
    ...
    break;
case xyz:
    ...
    commonData = Manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    break;
default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

I tried simply declaring, initialising and using the variable (`int someInt`) just inside that `case`, but this gave me a few compile errors... Having come across this question on SO: [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement), I tried doing what the answer suggested, and added `{}` to the `case` in question, so my `switch` now looks like this:

```
switch(mode)
{
case abc:
    {
    ...
    struct commonData;
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    int someInt = 1;
    ...
    break;
    }
case xyz:
    ...
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    break;
default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

But I'm now getting compile errors that say: "undeclared identifier" on a variable (`commonData`) that is used inide the `xyz` case of the `switch`.

Having had a look into this- it seems that this variable is declared inside the `abc` case of the `switch`... So obviously, since I have added the `{}` to `abc`, by trying to use it outside `abc`, I am now trying to use it outside the scope of its declaration.

So why is it that I can't declare/ use `someInt` in the same way as `commonData` has been declared/ used without the need for the `{}` inside the `case` where it's declared?

Comment: struct TypeNameforStruct{ // struct members};

TypeNameforStruct commonData; ?

Comment: Huh? There is something off or incomplete with the code you posted. struct commonData does not declare a variable, but an incomplete type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why *some* variable declarations are not allowed in a `switch` statement is: it is illegal for `switch`-based control flow to jump over a variable initialisation.

In your case, I assume the type of `commonData` has trivial initialisation (no constructor and no non-trivial members), so declaring it is perfectly fine, as would be declaring just `int someInt;`. However, `int someInt = 1;` is not allowed, since the initialisation would be skipped whenever `mode` is not `abc`.

I can't quite see what you'd get from declaring `commonData` only once, except for saving some typing at the cost of obscuring the code ("where did `commonData` come from?" when reading a `case` block), which is never a good trade. So I would just use `{}` inside each `case` "block" and declare `commonData` in each one which needs it. Or declare `commonData` above the switch.

But if you *really* want the same `commonData` to be shared by all `case`s and yet local to the `switch` block, you can fine-tune the scopes. Something like this:

```
switch(mode)
{
    SomeType commonData;
case abc:
    {
    ...
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    int someInt = 1;
    ...
    break;
    }
case xyz:
    ...
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    break;
default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

or this:

```
switch(mode)
{
case abc:
    SomeType commonData;
    ...
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    {
    int someInt = 1;
    ...
    break;
    }
case xyz:
    ...
    commonData = manager->getDataByIndex(this->Data.particularData);
    break;
default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

But please, think of the next maintainer, and don't play such tricks.

---

The answer above assumes `struct commonData;` is actually a "typo" in your code: literally, it would forward-declare a type, and not declare a variable. But that matches neither usage in the rest of your code, nor the text of your question, so I took the liberty of fixing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- really helpful explanation.

Answer (score 9):

`{ .. }` creates a local scope, so your variable declaration won't be visible in the other one.

Add a declaration to each `case` with local scope, or, if you want to use the variable outside the switch statement, declare it before the `switch`.

Comment: Cheers- just thought of this. I don't want to use the variable outside the switch, but it seems it needs to be declared outside the switch so that it can be used inside just the one case.

Comment: That's not the case. You can create local scope in the switch, and add (and *use*) a variable only to that scope. But that's not what you're doing in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Use brackets. Example:

```
switch (int number) {
    case 3: { 
        int n = 5; 
        n = n*4; // random
    } break;

    case 4: {
        int a = 4;
        //  n is out of scope
    } break;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The binary code order of switch statement might be different than the orignal code because compiler would optimize the code into a binary-search tree. Thus the cross scope variables are not allowed.