# static class members and switches

Tags: c++, class, int, switch-statement, constants

I got a little problem, I get an error:
`"C2361: initialization of *identifier* is skipped by 'default' label"`

I use an internal class member to set the chosen approach used in my methods.
The methods use this internal member (`static int`) with a switch to determine which approach was set.
The switch needs an intial value when compiling, so I decided to use a `static const int`. However, VS is still unhappy, and I can't change the `static const int` as well.
I am pretty sure this ain't a big deal, but it's quite frustrating.

example:

```
class test{
    public:
    static int Val;
    static void setVal(int val);
    static int doStuff(void);
};

test::setVal(int val){
    Val=val;
}

test::doStuff(){
    switch(Val){
    case 1:
    // do stuff
    case 2:
    // do other stuff
    default:
    // do default
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any tips or solutions

Comment: What's "an intern class member"?

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement ? Maybe your static variable is not the culprit.

Comment: Your code is missing details.  At a guess, the code in `do other stuff` is declaring and initializing a variable.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbin: Simple: its my static int Val int this example

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: do other stuff ist just a change of behaviour, in fact I chose from where my program gets values, and how these are processed, let's say in case 1: I multiply values, and in case 2 I just add the given values. In fact i just don't wanna pass the case value each time a method is called, so I tried this approach with using as case value the static int Val of the class.

Comment: That error is telling you that you have code like `case 2: int i = 7; break; default:` where the variable initialized in the second case is still visible and live at the default label.

Comment: @Y.S. I'm asking you to explain your terminology. "intern"?

Comment: @Ligthness Races in Orbin: Yea it's no real intern member since it ain't protected nor private. I used intern since it is a value stored in my class, and so seemed somehow logic.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Thanks a lot, I did actually declare a return value in one case and throw exceptions at the other not yet implemented cases, so you were right on spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous problems with he code you have posted. But assuming there are no other issues the following code will produce what you are experiencing:

### test.h:

```
class test{
    public:
    static int Val;
    static void setVal(int val);
    static int doStuff(void);
};
```

### test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int test::Val = 0;

void
test::setVal(int val){
    Val=val;
}

int
test::doStuff(){
    switch(Val){
    case 1:
    // dostuff
        int apples = 1; /* problem line */
        break;
    default:
    // do default
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Will produce the error:

`error C2361: initialization of 'apples' is skipped by 'default' label`

The reason for this is because you are trying to initialise a variable within the `case` statement. Visual Studio is complaining that there is no guarantee that the variable will be initialised because the case statement may be skipped over.

The question [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement) gives the reason for this behavior.

But to put it briefly there is a chance that your code will jump to a case statement after the initialisation of your variable and visual studio does not allow such a case since it may lead to undefined behavior.

To quote the standard ( ISO C++ '03 - 6.7/3 ):

> A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has POD type (3.9) and is declared without an initializer (8.5)

Comment: In his code, could the problem have been `switch(Val)` since he didn't initialize `test::Val` in his code, but you initialized `test::Val` in your code?

Comment: @JonnyHenly He posted the error he was getting up the top. An un-initialised static gives a different error: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`. My code assumes everything is correct and he is only getting that one error. For the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Shouldn't he have gotten `error LNK2001: ...` before `error C3261`? Not saying anything is wrong with your answer, I'm just curious. Just noticed you edited your last comment adding the assumption.

Comment: @JonnyHenly On my compiler he would get `C2361` before `LNK2001`, so he could still get the `LNK2001` error after he has fixed this one. So you might still be correct.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: Yes, I got both of em, but the initialisiation was what I was actually looking for, simple things lead to huge questionmarks, or so, Thanks a lot guys - the linker error came after c2361...