# Return by reference inside a switch statement

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, reference, switch-statement

I want to return by reference to a variable that's inside a switch, like for example:

```
sometype & getbar();

void foo() {
        switch ( {statement} ) {
        case {statement}:
            sometype & handle = getbar();
        ...
```

But I'm getting compiler errors:

> initialization of 'identifier' is skipped by 'case' label
>
> initialization of 'identifier' is skipped by 'default' label

And it looks like it's not possible to do this:

```
void foo() {
        sometype & handle;
        switch ( {statement} ) {
        case {statement}:
            handle = getbar();
        ...
```

Because a reference variable requires initialization.

Is there a way to do this with keeping the switch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Enclose the body of the case statement in brackets, like this:

```
case {statement}:
{
    sometype & handle = getbar();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Woah it works! What's the difference?

Comment: @kuhaku, Cases are special labels and C++ doesn't let you skip over variable initialization by jumping to a label.

Comment: @kuhaku - See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/92439/18882

Comment: @kuhaku - case statements are like labels, jumped to by the switch condition. This means that the entire switch expression has a single scope. The compiler complains if there are any variables whose initialization could be "skipped over" in this scope, so by creating a new scope with the brackets, the variable initialization error/warning is resolved.