# Initializing arrays in switch case statements

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization, switch-statement

Whimsically, I initialized the following array `c` in a switch statement fully expecting my compiler to say *NO you can't do that* but much to my surprise it compiled in MSVC, GCC and Clang. Online [example](http://rextester.com/FRB5433)

I'm assuming that the standard allows it, in which case my question is why? ... considering that declaration and initialization of non-arrays is NOT allowed in case statements.

```
int main()
{
    char ch;

    switch( ch )
    {
    case 'x':
        //int a = 42; // NOT OKAY
        break;

    case 'y':
        int b;
        b = 42;    // OKAY

    case 'z':
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };  // OKAY (Huh???)
        break;
    };
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the compiler to not like that? `c` is totally valid in the context of `switch(ch)`, but not visible outside.

Comment: It is OK to define (locally) and initialize an array however you won't be able to use it outside the `switch` scope... (also `int a = 42;` should perfectly work) (... no reason to tag C++ here)

Comment: This is just a MWE. I intend to use `c` in the case statement.

Comment: @AlexLop. The question relates to C and C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change your example to

```
int main()
{
    char ch;

    switch( ch )
    {
    case 'x':
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };
        break;

    case 'z':
        int a = 42;
        break;
    }
}
```

you'll notice that the error now occurs for the array, but not for the `int`.

Intialisation is actually allowed for the last case.

The rule is not "you're not allowed to initialise a variable in a `case`" but "you're not allowed to jump across a variable initialisation."

And it's impossible to jump across the initialisation in the last case.

The reason for the rule is that a variable declared in a `case` is in scope in the subsequent cases, and jumping to a subsequent case would bypass the initialisation.

This becomes (slightly) clearer if you rewrite as a goto-sequence, as the same rules about scope and initialisation apply:

```
if (ch == 'x') goto x;
if (ch == 'y') goto y;
if (ch == 'z') goto z;
goto end;
{
  x:
    int a = 42;  // goto y or z breaks this
    goto end;
  y:
    int b;      // uninitialised, so OK
    b = 42;
    goto end;
  z:
    int c[2] = {0, 1};  // No label after this, so can't jump across, so OK
    goto end;
}
end:
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler would issue an error if a jump to a case label bypassed the initialized array. For example

```
    switch( ch )
    {
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };  // OKAY (Huh???)
    case 'x':
        //int a = 42; // NOT OKAY
        break;

    case 'y':
        int b;
        b = 42;    // OKAY

    case 'z':
//        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };  // OKAY (Huh???)
        break;
    }
```

or

```
    switch( ch )
    {
    case 'x':
        //int a = 42; // NOT OKAY
        break;

    case 'y':
        int b;
        b = 42;    // OKAY

    case 'z':
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };  // OKAY (Huh???)
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

However in the original program neither jump bypasses the initialized array.

Here is a more simplified demonstrative program.
This will compile successfully

```
int main() 
{
    goto L1;

    {
        L1:;
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };
    }       
}
```

while this will issue an error

```
int main() 
{
    goto L1;

    {
        int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };
        L1:;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Nice example with the goto! I see what the committee meant to do by preventing jumps past initializations but its not  bullet proof as jumps past deferred initializations are not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is totally fine where it is. You are declaring (and initializing) it in the lexical scope of `switch(ch)`, where it is allowed to live, be initialized, and be referenced by other operations (after it was declared).

What wouldn't work is referencing it outside of the `switch`, like so:

```
switch(ch) {
  ...
  case 'z':
    int c[2] = { 0 , 1 };  // OKAY (Huh???)
    break;
};

some_operation(c);
```

The only situation in which this would be forbidden would be if you had *another* `case` statement that uses the same variable. As `case` statements are just labels (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)), you could potentially just skip the initialization of a later-on used variable.

So, the compiler let's you do that as long as you use the variable only in one label, but not in multiple.