# c++: why can we declare a variable in case of switch

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, switch-statement

```
int i;
i = 2;
switch(i)
{
    case 1: 
        int k;
        break;
    case 2:
        k = 1;
        cout<<k<<endl;
        break;
}
```

I don't know why the code above works.

Here, we can never go into case 1 but why we can use `k` in case 2?

Comment: you think that's bad? look at [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

Comment: Switches are rather weird; if you're looking for scope, {} are your friend.

Comment: @TemplateRex That question is about why you can't. This question is about why you can.

Comment: @Barry, Still, the top answer does do a good job of explaining this one.

Comment: @Barry potato, po-tah-to, the first answer of the linked Q&A goes into great depth about switch scoping

Comment: @chris The top one doesn't answer this one at all.

Comment: I've just noticed that answer is closed, I've wrote such an explanatory answer with references to standard. :) Never Mind.

Comment: @PcAF   oh I really want to see your explanatory. I didnt close the answer...

Comment: @TemplateRex I just don't want to argue.

Comment: @PcAF   In fact I still don't know why `k` has been declared even if we never go into case 1.

Comment: @Thomas Did you read that linked Q&A? It explains things well.

Comment: @PcAF   hmm, I think I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Reopened. This was closed as a duplicate of "why **can't** we define...", while this question is "why **can** we define...".

Comment: @PcAF   If you wish, leave your answer for us  :D

Comment: @Thomas I already posted it on linked Q&A, However this question is not duplicate now, so I post it also here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 questions:

**1. Why can I declare a variable after `case` label?**

It's because in C++ label has to be in form:

N3337 6.1/1

> labeled-statement:
>
> ...
>
> - *attribute-specifier-seqopt* `case` `constant-expression` : `statement`
>
> ...

And in `C++` *declaration statement* is also considered as *statement* (as opposed to `C`):

N3337 6/1:

> *statement*:
>
> ...
>
> - *declaration-statement*
>
> ...

**2. Why can I jump over variable declaration and then use it?**

Because:
N3337 6.7/3

> It is possible to transfer into a block, **but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization**. A
>   program that jumps
>   (The **transfer from** the condition of a **switch statement to a case label is considered a jump** in this respect.)
>
> **from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed** **unless the variable has scalar type**, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the
>   preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

Since `k` is of *scalar type*, and is not initialized at point of declaration jumping over it's declaration is possible. This is semantically equivalent:

```
goto label;

int x;

label:
cout << x << endl;
```

However this wouldn't work if `x` was initialized at point of declaration:

```
 goto label;

    int x = 58; //error, jumping over declaration with initialization

    label:
    cout << x << endl;
```