# Declarations in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, declaration

Consider this C-code, where `foo` is an `int`:

```
switch(foo){
    case 1: {
        int bla = 255;
        case 2:
            printf("case12 %d\n", bla);
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("case3  %d\n", bla);
    }
};
```

For different values of `foo` the code gives the following output:

```
case12 255   # foo=1
case12 255   # foo=2
case3  0     # foo=3
```

I have a problem understanding `foo=3`. The line that declares `bla` and defines its value should not execute, when `foo=3`. The switch statement should jump right to the label for `case 3:`. Yet there is no warning, so `bla` seems to have been declared at least. It might be used uninitialized and its value just happens to be `0`, though. Can you explain, what's happening in "case 3", and why this is legal C-code?

Comment: You don't need that semicolon after the last `}`.

Comment: Strangely enough, GCC accepts the code in the C mode (with a warning), but rejects it in the C++ mode.

Comment: Not that strange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement?rq=1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: C++, unlike C, forbids jumping over an initialization. See section 6.7 ([stmt.dcl]) of the C++ standard, paragraph 3.

Comment: Do NOT nest the 'case' statements.  That is not valid C code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `switch` statement is essentially a computed `goto`. The `case` labels can appear anywhere within the (usually compound) statement controlled by the `switch`, even within nested blocks.

The declaration `int bla = 255;` creates an `int` object `bla` whose lifetime is the execution of the enclosing block and whose name is visible from the point of its declaration to the end of the block.

If the `switch` statement causes control to jump to the `case 2:` or `case 3:` label, it jumps into the scope of `bla` but jumps *past* its initialization. The value of `bla` is then garbage (not random, not necessarily `0`) and in fact trying to refer to its value has undefined behavior.

You can do the same thing with a `goto` statement

Don't do that.

(For gcc, you'll get a warning if you compile with `-Wall`, or `-Wextra`, or `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`.)

(For another abuse of the `switch` statement, see [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't see why the `bla` exists at all. Naively, I'd assume, the declaration would be skipped as well (not just the initialization). But obviously the code provides `bla`.

Comment: @con-f-use: It exists because control entered the block in which it's defined. Its *lifetime* starts when control reaches (or jumps over) the opening `{` and ends when control reaches the closing `}`. The initialization doesn't occur until control reaches the declaration -- and doesn't occur at all if the declaration is jumped over. (C++ forbids this kind of jump.)

Comment: @con-f-use: If the definition of of `bla` would be skipped the code could not compile. As it compiles this proves that `bla` is defined.