# semicolon after the for loop block

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    };
}
```

Is there any case that the semicolon after the `for` loop would affect the program ?

Comment: You could add 100 semicolons and it wouldn't have an effect. Would probably result in identical compiled code.

Comment: Off topic, but It can be useful inside a `switch` nevertheless. Check the third answer of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement) if it interests you.

Comment: Off topic: format your code.

Comment: What's going on with the "tau" in the first `std::`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::end` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon is an empty expression statement.

From section 6.2 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

> The expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5). All side
>   effects from an expression statement are completed before the next
>   statement is executed. **An expression statement with the expression
>   missing is called a null statement.** [ Note: Most statements are
>   expression statements — usually assignments or function calls. A null
>   statement is useful to carry a label just before the } of a compound
>   statement and to supply a null body to an iteration statement such as
>   a while statement (6.5.1). —end note ]

This will be more clear with some reformatting:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
        std::cout <<"Hello"<<std::endl;
    }
    ;
}
```

The presence of this null statement has no effect on the program.

Comment: Let's cite the C++ standard when the question is about C++.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The question was tagged for both, so I initially went with C.  The code itself is obviously C++, so I removed the C tag and changed the reference.

Comment: @dbush thank you for the answer

Comment: @dbush: Good stuff. Unfortunately, C++ only tells us what the construct is called.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The semicolon is not even "attached" to the loop; it's just an empty statement sitting there, effectively on its own.

Comment: I don't know why recent GCCs don't warn on this; IME, older ones did.

Comment: clang-tidy will hepfully point it out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change anything. It just evaluates to an empty statement.

It's completely harmless. Just a bit of pointless clutter.