# C++ syntax I don't understand

Tags: c++, syntax

I've found a C++ code that has this syntax:

```
void MyClass::method()
{
    beginResetModel();

    {
        // Various stuff
    }

    endResetModel();
}
```

I've no idea why there are `{ }` after a line ending with `;` but it seems there is no problem to make it compile and run. Is it possible this as something to do with the fact that the code may be asynchronous (I'm not sure yet)? Or maybe the `{ }` are only here to delimit a part of the code and don't really make a difference but honestly I doubt this. I don't know, does someone has any clue what this syntax mean ?

More info: There is no other reference to `beginResetModel`, `resetModel` or `ResetModel` in the whole project (searched with grep). Btw the project is a Qt one. Maybe it's another Qt-related macro I haven't heard of.

Comment: {} will create another scope

Comment: The `{}` brackets just open and close a block. Like the `{}` in a `for` loop. They limit the scope of the variables declared in that block to the block. So variables declared inside the `{}` aren't visible outside.

Comment: all great software engineers have one thing in common - they have read at least one instruction manual.

Comment: @RichardHodges and then thrown it away in the knowledge that they know better.

Comment: Do you understand `if (foo) bar();`? If so, then how can you not understand that `{ /* stuff */ }` is a statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `{}` will create a [new scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). In your case, any variable created in those braces will cease to exist at the `}` in the end.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>    beginResetModel();
>    {
>        // Various stuff
>    }
>    endResetModel()
> ```

The open and close braces in your code are a *very* important feature in C++, as they delimit a new *scope*. You can appreciate the power of this in combination with another powerful language feature: *destructors*.

So, suppose that inside those braces you have code that creates various objects, like graphics models, or whatever.

Assuming that these objects are instances of classes that allocate resources (e.g. textures on the video card), and those classes have *destructors* that release the allocated resources, you are guaranteed that, at the `}`, these destructors are *automatically* invoked.

In this way, all the allocated resources are *automatically* released, before the code outside the closing curly brace, e.g. before the call to `endResetModel()` in your sample.

This *automatic* and *deterministic* resource management is a key powerful feature of C++.

---

Now, suppose that you remove the curly braces, and your method looks like this:

```
void MyClass::method()
{
    beginResetModel();

    // {
        // Various stuff
    // }

    endResetModel();
}
```

Now, all the objects created in the `Various stuff` section of code will be destroyed *before* the `}` that terminates the `MyClass::method()`, but *after* the call to `endResetModel()`.

So, in this case, you end up with the `endResetModel()` call, followed by other release code that runs *after* it. This may cause bugs.
On the other hand, the curly braces that define a new scope enclosed in `begin/endResetModel()` do guarantee that *all* the objects created inside this scope are destroyed *before* `endResetModel()` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` delimits a scope. That means that any variable declared inside there is not accessible outside of it and is erased from memory once the `}` is reached. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    ~MyClass(){
        cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    {
        int x = 3;
        MyClass foo;
        cout << x << endl;    //Prints 3
    }    //Here "Destructor called" is printed since foo is cleared from the memory

    cout << x << endl;    //Compiler error, x isn't defined here

    return 0;
}
```

Usually scopes are used for functions, loops, if-statements, etc, but you're perfectly allowed to use scopes without any statement before them. This can be particularly useful to declare variables inside a `switch` ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92439/4284627) explains why).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the curly braces create a new scope, but maybe the interesting thing is *why* would you want to do that - that is, what is the difference between using it and not using it. There are cases where scopes are obviously necessary, such as with `if` or `for` blocks; if you don't create a scope after them you can only have one statement. Another possible reason is that maybe you use one variable in one part of the function and do not one it to be used outside of that part, so you put it into its own scope. However, the main use of scopes out of control statements has to do with [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). When you declare an instance variable (not a pointer or reference), it is always initialized; when it goes out of scope, it is always destroyed. This can be used to define blocks that require some setup at the beginning and some tear down at the end (if you are familiar with Python, similar to `with` blocks).

Take this example:

```
#include <mutex>

void fun(std::mutex & mutex) {
    // 1. Perform some computations...
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        // 2. Operations in this scope are performed with the mutex locked
    }
    // 3. More computations...
}
```

In this example, part 2 is only run after the mutex has been acquired, and is released before part 3 starts. If you remove the additional scope:

```
#include <mutex>

void fun(std::mutex & mutex) {
    // 1. Perform some computations...
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    // 2. Operations in this scope are performed with the mutex locked
    // 3. More computations...
}
```

In this case the mutex is acquired before starting part 2, but it is held until part 3 is complete (possibly producing more interlocking between threads than necessary). Note, however, that in both cases there was no need to specify when the lock is released; `std::lock_guard` is responsible for *both* acquiring the lock on construction and releasing it on destruction (i.e. when it goes out of scope).