# Compiling Game of Life (C) with Notepad++

Tags: c, compiler-errors, notepad++

I have wrote a Game of Life simulation in C and now want to compile it.
I have tried it with Notepad++ using NppExec. I have entered this into the 
Execute Command:

```
 npp_save cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe -g
 "$(FILE_NAME)" -o "$(FILE_NAME)".exe -L C:\MinGW\bin\
```

This is my main function:

```
int main() {
    const int n = ED; const int m = ZD;  //1.Dim/2.Dim
    char matr[ED][ZD]; 
    char lager[ED][ZD];
    int alz; //Anzahl lebender Zellen

        switch (Menu("\n1 - Erstelle Zufallsmatrix\n2 - Lade Matrix 1\n3 - Lade Matrix 2\n4 - Lade Matrix 3\n\n0 - Beenden", 5, "\n >>>> ")) {
        case 0: exit(0); break;
        case 1: 
            int prozent = Einlesen("Prozentsatz der Lebenden Zellen? Wertebereich: 0 bis 100\nEingabe:", 0, 100, 5);
            create_matr(matr, n, m, &alz, prozent); 
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 2: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 1,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 3: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 2,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 4: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 3, &alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        }
     return 0;
```

This is the error I get now:

error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
    int prozent = Einlesen("Prozentsatz der Lebenden Zellen? Wertebereich: 0 bis 100\nEingabe:", 0, 100, 5);
    ^~~

Ignore the german words, what do I change to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the gap between -L and C:\MinGW\bin\?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the error is to do with declaring a variable inside a switch case. See [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement)

In order to resolve this you can either do this:

```
switch (Menu("\n1 - Erstelle Zufallsmatrix\n2 - Lade Matrix 1\n3 - Lade Matrix 2\n4 - Lade Matrix 3\n\n0 - Beenden", 5, "\n >>>> ")) {
        case 0: exit(0); break;
        case 1: {
            int prozent = Einlesen("Prozentsatz der Lebenden Zellen? Wertebereich: 0 bis 100\nEingabe:", 0, 100, 5);
            create_matr(matr, n, m, &alz, prozent); 
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            } break;
        case 2: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 1,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 3: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 2,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 4: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 3, &alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        }
     return 0;
```

Or this:

```
int prozent;
switch (Menu("\n1 - Erstelle Zufallsmatrix\n2 - Lade Matrix 1\n3 - Lade Matrix 2\n4 - Lade Matrix 3\n\n0 - Beenden", 5, "\n >>>> ")) {
        case 0: exit(0); break;
        case 1:
            prozent = Einlesen("Prozentsatz der Lebenden Zellen? Wertebereich: 0 bis 100\nEingabe:", 0, 100, 5);
            create_matr(matr, n, m, &alz, prozent); 
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        case 2: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 1,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 3: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 2,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 4: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 3, &alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        }
     return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you the 2nd version fixed it for me!