# Why we can access variables inside other case labels of the switch?

Tags: c++

```
switch (false)
{
case true:
    int jval;
    break;

case false:
    jval = 18;
    cout << jval;
    break;

}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am able to access jval in this case ?

Comment: Because you didn't wrap your case results in {} thus defining the scope.  10001 reasons to always use {} after a case statement; number 3

Comment: That feels like a deep dark corner left over from "C".  Legal, but not something I would want to see.  It is visible because case statements don't define their own scope and hence we are trained to use braces.

Comment: Didn't you get warning for that? if not, try `-Wall -Wextra` with GCC/Clang.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Lookup _Duff's Device_. Nifty thing sometimes (especially with _loop unrolling_). Not really a _"dark corner"_.

Comment: @Nawaz None of gcc 7, clang 5 and MSVC 19 produce a warning for this unless you provide additional warnings flags.

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question is because. I thought that when we reach the right cases everything before it is ignored right?

Comment: So why the definition is visible here and not  rather ignored?

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan Heavily related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: Variable declarations don't have to be executed, they're just part of the block. If it contains an initialization, that won't be done unless you execute it.

Comment: @Nawaz why should you get a warning?  Scope is defined by {} in c++; and there aren't any.  This means that whatever the value of the item you're switching on, all variables in all the cases can be put on the stack.

Comment: ROFL - @TheDude I've used duff's device for embedded work in the past and I would say that this is indeed a deep dark corner of the language.  :)  In seriousness though, it illustrates a way to get an assembly jump table effectively into C code.

Comment: @Michael _" I've used duff's device for embedded work ..."_ Of course, same same ;-). I'd say it's a bit of black magic you can still do properly with the full compliant c++ language. It's fun to use it to program bare metal.

Comment: If jval were initialized in the declaration then the program would be ill-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable scope is the part between curly brackets, not between `case` and `break`.
Thus, a variable declared in one case is in scope in all subsequent cases.

It may be clearer if you look at the equivalent formulation using `goto`:

```
// "Jump table"
if (false == true)
    goto case_true;
if (false == false)
    goto case_false;
goto switch_end;
// switch body begins here.
{
case_true:
    int jval;
    goto switch_end;

case_false:
    jval = 18;
    cout << jval;
    goto switch_end;
}
// switch ends here.
switch_end:
```

(This is more or less literally what a simple-minded compiler will translate a `switch` into – a sequence of jumps and a trivially transformed body.)

Note that you will get an error if you try to initialise `jval`:

```
switch (false)
{
case true:
    int jval = 13;   // Nope.
    cout << jval
    break;
case false:
    jval = 18;
    cout << jval;
    break;
}
```

because you're not allowed to jump across a variable initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

The cases are only labels, while break just means jump to the end of the switch scope block.
The lifetime of a variable is within the scope block (`{ }`) from the place it was declared to the closing `}`.

Also, if you don't put break and enter the first `case` statement, the program flow will pass to the next one.
So the code in the second `case` statement, got access to that variable.

If you want to not have access to it, guard it in another `{ }` scope block, to limit it's life time.