# Deleting printf(""); breaks my program! I'm getting error: expected expression" making a char after switch case

Tags: c

Is this a normal error that will happen with just a blank method?  I used a custom Makefile btw.

```
case MODE: //mode is just an enum stackoverflow

  printf("");

  char temp = '5';
```

CSftp.c:335:9: error: expected expression
        char temp = '5';

deleting printf(""); causes the error to appear.  Or is this a sympton from a problem far away.

Comment: The fact you're using a custom makefile or using make is totally irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 7):

Variables should not be declared in a `case` without being correctly scoped by an enclosing `{..}` block. A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92439/13164962). Declare `char temp` before the switch statement or enclose the code for the case.

**Option 1:**

```c
char temp; 
switch(condition){
    ...
    case MODE:
        temp = '5';
        ...
}
```

**Option 2:**

```c
switch(condition){
    ...
    case MODE:
    {
        char temp = '5';
        ...
    }
    case NEXT:
        ...
}
```

Comment: Perfectly valid to add a block-scope, e.g. `{ .... }` within a case and declare variables within.

Comment: The advice is OK but the explanation is wrong, and at any rate it doesn’t explain the problem OP is seeing.

Answer (score 7):

GCC 9.3 has a more easily understandable error message:

> a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement

That is, C’s syntax simply forbids this because a `case` label needs to be attached to a syntactic *statement*, and declarations in C aren’t statements. But *compound statements* are statements, which is why surrounding the whole thing by `{…}` works.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to declare variable in the case add the block there:

```
switch(x)
{
    case MODE: //mode is just an enum stackoverflow
    {
        printf("");   

        char temp = '5';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can only assign a value to a variable in case unless you use a block

```
    case MODE: 
    {
        printf("");   

        char temp = '5';
    }
```

but note that you only have this variable in this statement after you exit the block variable `temp` is no longer visible.