# What does a gcc error about undefined references, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-reference

My c++ program was giving e errors when I tried to compile so I fixed them all, but then it gave me a completely different set of errors about undefined references. Here's the code for armyGame.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int players;

std::cout << "Please enter the number of players, between 2 and 6:";

std::cin >> players;

switch (players) {
    case 1:
    std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again.";
    return 18;

    case 2:
    int p12, p22;

    case 3:
    int p13, p23, p33;

    case 4:
    int p14, p24, p34, p44;

        case 5:
        int p15, p25, p35, p45, p55;

        case 6:
        int p16, p26, p36, p46, p56, p66;
        }


    }
```

Here's my input to gcc:

```
gcc armyGame.cpp
```

And here's the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3SlY1r.o: in function `main':
armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `std::cin'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3SlY1r.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: armyGame.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any guesses?

Comment: Try compiling with `g++` instead of `gcc`?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `c++ what is an undefined reference` into a search engine? How about `c++ undefined reference to std::cin`?

Comment: Irrelevant: the `pXX` declarations in your switch block are also invalid. See [Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: The definitions in the case statement are valid, but useless. When the program starts using them things could get ugly, but for now they're sitting there collecting dust and probably being optimized out.

Comment: Side note: Any time you find yourself with sequentially named or numbered variables, odds are very good your program will be a lot easier to write with an array or [a library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).