# Why a declaration is not a statement in C?

Tags: c, programming-languages, language-design

The following example is illegal C program, which is confusing and shows that a declaration is not a statement in C language.

```c
int main() {
  if (1) int x;
}
```

I've read the specification of C ([N2176](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)) and I know C language distinguish declaration and statement in the syntax specification. I told my teacher who teaches compiler, and he seems not believe it and I cannot convince him unless I showed him the specification.

So, I am also really confused. Why C is designed like this? Why a declaration is not a statement in C? How to convince someone of the reason of this design?

Comment: Because that's how the language was designed... I doubt you'll find any rationale anywhere. Checking _The Development of the C Language_ by Dennis Ritchie, he basically says "because that's how B and/or BCPL were designed". And back in the 1960s somewhere things just happened at a whim: programming languages were highly experimental and they didn't have anything to compare with.

Comment: At one level the answer is, "just because".  It's a little like asking, "Why is 'apple' a noun and not a verb in English?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no apparent grammatical or technical semantic reason that a declaration cannot appear wherever a statement may appear, this appears to be largely due to history and lack of utility.

### Considering the Grammar

Statements enter the C grammar in the *function-definition* rule, in which a *compound-statement* appears. A *compound-statement* allows a *statement*. Then inspecting the replacements for a *statement* reveals the places where a *statement* may appear but a *declaration* may not:

- In a *labeled-statement*, after a label followed by `:`.
- In a *selection-statement*, after the `)` of an `if` or a `switch` or after an `else`.
- In an *iteration-statement*, after the `)` of a `while` or `for` or after a `do`.

The following is not a formal analysis of the grammar, but it appears the places where a statement may appear but a declaration may not are quite limited: After the `:` that ends a label, after a keyword (`else` or `do`) or after the closing `)` for a `(` that immediately follows a keyword (`if`, `switch`, `while`, or `for`). These seem to me like unambiguous points in the grammar, where it should be as easy to distinguish declarations and statements as it is to do so after a `;` in a *compound-statement*.

Therefore, I do not think there is a grammatical reason not to allow a declaration to appear anywhere a statement may appear (or, equivalently, to define a declaration as a kind of statement).

### Considering the Semantics

Now consider the semantic effects of allowing declarations in the places where currently a statement may appear but a declaration may not.

In the case of a *labeled-statement*, where we desired to have `label: declaration`, we can use `label: ; declaration`, where we have inserted a null statement after the `:`. The result is a defined code sequence with semantic effect equivalent to what we would desire to have by allowing a declaration immediately after the label.

In the other cases, where we desire to have `declaration`, we can use `{ declaration }`. Again, the result is a defined code sequence with semantic effect equivalent to what we would desire to have by allowing a bare declaration. That effect is minimal; any expressions in the declaration (in array declarators or initializers) will be evaluated, but anything that is declared goes out of scope immediately. Note that even if the scope were not ended by the closing `}`, it is ended by the fact that the C standard defines each of these places to be a block. (C 2018 6.8.4 3 says the substatement of a *selection-statement* is a block, and 6.8.5 5 says the loop body of an *iteration-statement* is a block.)

Nonetheless, this shows there is no technical semantic impediment to allowing a declaration wherever a statement may appear.

### Conclusion

Since the grammar and semantics of C apparently do not preclude allowing a declaration to be a type of statement, we are left with reasons of history and utility. In C as described in the first edition of Kernighan and Ritchie’s *The C Programming Language*, the locations of declarations were limited. Inside functions, they could only appear at the start of a compound statement. A declaration could not follow a statement. As we see from modern C, there was no grammatical or semantic reason for this limitation; we can allow declarations anywhere within a compound statement. So it seems simply that, around 1978, work on the language had not progressed that far.

Similarly, it seems that current work on C has not gone to the point of allowing a declaration to appear anywhere a statement may appear, as if it were a type of statement, even though there may be no technical impediment. However, in this case, there is less motivation for loosening the rules. Of the above cases, the only one that is of much use is allowing a declaration in a labeled statement. And, as its desired effect is easily accomplished by inserting a null statement, there is likely insufficient motivation to change compilers and to advocate for the changes in the C committee.

Comment: related info about `switch` and declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830820/5959593

Answer (score -1):

That's because a declaration doesn't instruct the compiler to **do** anything, it's purely informative for the compiler; at least by the standard. Compilers may do something if they see a declaration, the standard does not forbid it either but it doesn't require them to do anything if they only see a declaration and whatever it declares is never used within any statement.

Consider this code:

```
int main ( ) 
{
    int x;
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What do you think will `int x;` do? You are declaring that `x` is of  type `int` but you are never using `x` anywhere in the rest of the code. The compiler doesn't even have to reserve any memory on stack for it. It may to so but it isn't required to do so.

The standard allows the compiler to create exactly the same code as if you had written:

```
int main ( ) 
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

There is simply nothing a compiler must do if you let it know the type of a variable. This variable doesn't have to exist anywhere at all unless it is ever used by a statement.

C is not an interpreted language where every piece of code instructs the interpreter to directly do something. C is a compiled language which means you tell the compiler to generate CPU code for you that performs the actions you described in a predefined language. So there is no one-to-one relationship between the code you write and the CPU code the compiler generates.

You may write

```
int x = a / 8;
```

but the CPU code that the compiler generate may be equivalent to

```
int x = a >> 3;
```

As that is exactly the same thing and if shifting is faster than division (and you can bet it is), the compiler does not have to generate a division just because you told it to do so. What you told the compiler is "I want x to be one eighth of a" and the compiler will be like "okay, I'll generate code that makes this happen" but how the compiler is making it happen is up to the compiler.

Thus the compiler only needs to translate statements to CPU code. Actually only statements that have an effect but to find out about that expensive analysis may be required so it's no standard violation to translate all statements to code, even those that do nothing. A declaration on its own has never an effect, it just lets the compiler know the type of a variable or function, which may become important in statements later on but only if the variable/function is ever actually used.

Comment: "The code the compiler will generate is exactly identical to the code the compiler generates when you compile" That's not true in general. On GCC with no optimizations for example, the version with `x` will move the stack pointer to make space for `x`. It's also not accurate that a syntactic element must "do something" in order to be considered a statement. The empty statement does absolutely nothing by definition and is still a statement.

Comment: @sepp2k C doesn't even require a system to have a stack in the first place, so how would a compiler reserve space on stack on a system that has no stacks? You are making assumption about the C-language based on a specific implementation (GCC) running on a specific system you tend to know. From a language perspective a compiler is not require to do anything when seeing a declaration. And there is no empty statement in C, there is only a Null statement https://0cn.de/hdyt and this statement exists to explicitly tell the compiler to **do** nothing (it's also an instruction on what to do).

Comment: Obviously a declaration can do something, just add an initializer. `if (1) int x = do_stuff();` isn't valid C either.

Comment: @Lundin Then it's not longer just a declaration, as the assignment is a statement and the entire thing is a definition. Yet only the assignment is a statement and if you just put the assignment there, without declaration, it is valid code.

Comment: @Mecki I wasn't making an assumption, I was giving a counter example to your false assumption that all compilers act a certain way (generating the same code in both cases). Obviously the standard doesn't say anything about it, but you were arguing in terms of implementation that it's not a statement because compilers generate the same code whether it's there or not, which is not (always) true and at any rate not a meaningful way to define what a statement is.

Comment: And with regards to `int x = do_stuff();`. Both `int x;` and `int x = do_stuff();` are declarations as well as definitions. Neither are statements or assignments.

Comment: @sepp2k My answer is not about what compilers do but about what the C standard requires compilers to do. Compilers are free to whatever they want as long as they don't violate the standard but the standard does not require a compiler to do anything at all or create any CPU code if it sees a declaration. If you disagree, please quote where the standard requires them to do something. And no, a declaration is no definition, the standard clearly distinguishes both.

Answer (score -1):

If it **were** valid, what would you like this program to **do** ? :

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
if (argc > 1) int x=42;

printf("%d\n", x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `if (argc > 1) int x=function_with_side_effects();`.

Comment: Don't complicate things ;-!

Comment: My point is that a declaration _could_ contain side effects and relevant application logic. That's not why C separates statements and declarations - it simply does and there's unlikely any rationale for or against it.

Comment: The purpose of my answer/example is to illustrate that the *feature* would not add any value. It would only complicate things. (is `x` defined in this scope? How about `if (function_call()) int x;` ?)

Comment: One could argue that `if (argc > 1) int x=function_with_side_effects();` behaves the same as `if (argc > 1) (void) function_with_side_effects();` in C, so the first isn't really needed. In a language with user-defined types, the initalization of such types could also have side-effects so allowing it would make more sense there.

Comment: Side effects only compicate things. The issue is that depending on (runtime) program state, `x` is / isnot in scope.